# What does 'super' do in Python? - difference between super().__init__() and explicit superclass __init__()

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, super

What's the difference between:

```
class Child(SomeBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
```

and:

```
class Child(SomeBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        SomeBaseClass.__init__(self)
```

I've seen `super` being used quite a lot in classes with only single inheritance. I can see why you'd use it in multiple inheritance but am unclear as to what the advantages are of using it in this kind of situation.

---

<sub>This question is about technical implementation details and the distinction between different ways of accessing the base class `__init__` method. To close duplicate questions where OP is simply missing a `super` call and is asking why base class attributes aren't available, please use [Why don't my subclass instances contain the attributes from the base class (causing an AttributeError when I try to use them)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268603) instead.</sub>

Answer (score 356, accepted):

The benefits of `super()` in single-inheritance are minimal -- mostly, you don't have to hard-code the name of the base class into every method that uses its parent methods.

However, it's almost impossible to use multiple-inheritance without `super()`. This includes common idioms like mixins, interfaces, abstract classes, etc. This extends to code that later extends yours. If somebody later wanted to write a class that extended `Child` and a mixin, their code would not work properly.

Comment: can you provide an example by what you mean that with "it would not work properly"?

Answer (score 469):

### What's the difference?

```
SomeBaseClass.__init__(self)
```

means to call `SomeBaseClass`'s `__init__`. while

```
super().__init__()
```

means to call a bound `__init__` from the parent class that follows `SomeBaseClass`'s child class (the one that defines this method) in the instance's Method Resolution Order (MRO).

If the instance is a subclass of *this* child class, there may be a different parent that comes next in the MRO.

#### Explained simply

When you write a class, you want other classes to be able to use it. `super()` makes it easier for other classes to use the class you're writing.

As Bob Martin says, a good architecture allows you to postpone decision making as long as possible.

`super()` can enable that sort of architecture.

When another class subclasses the class you wrote, it could also be inheriting from other classes. And those classes could have an `__init__` that comes after this `__init__` based on the ordering of the classes for method resolution.

Without `super` you would likely hard-code the parent of the class you're writing (like the example does). This would mean that you would not call the next `__init__` in the MRO, and you would thus not get to reuse the code in it.

If you're writing your own code for personal use, you may not care about this distinction. But if you want others to use your code, using `super` is one thing that allows greater flexibility for users of the code.

#### Python 2 versus 3

This works in Python 2 and 3:

```
super(Child, self).__init__()
```

This only works in Python 3:

```
super().__init__()
```

It works with no arguments by moving up in the stack frame and getting the first argument to the method (usually `self` for an instance method or `cls` for a class method - but could be other names) and finding the class (e.g. `Child`) in the free variables (it is looked up with the name `__class__` as a free closure variable in the method).

I used to prefer to demonstrate the cross-compatible way of using `super`, but now that Python 2 is largely deprecated, I will demonstrate the Python 3 way of doing things, that is, calling `super` with no arguments.

#### Indirection with Forward Compatibility

What does it give you? For single inheritance, the examples from the question are practically identical from a static analysis point of view. However, using `super` gives you a layer of indirection with forward compatibility.

Forward compatibility is very important to seasoned developers. You want your code to keep working with minimal changes as you change it. When you look at your revision history, you want to see precisely what changed when.

You may start off with single inheritance, but if you decide to add another base class, you only have to change the line with the bases - if the bases change in a class you inherit from (say a mixin is added) you'd change nothing in this class.

In Python 2, getting the arguments to `super` and the correct method arguments right can be a little confusing, so I suggest using the Python 3 only method of calling it.

If you know you're using `super` correctly with single inheritance, that makes debugging less difficult going forward.

#### Dependency Injection

Other people can use your code and inject parents into the method resolution:

```
class SomeBaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('SomeBaseClass.__init__(self) called')
    
class UnsuperChild(SomeBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        print('UnsuperChild.__init__(self) called')
        SomeBaseClass.__init__(self)
    
class SuperChild(SomeBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        print('SuperChild.__init__(self) called')
        super().__init__()
```

Say you add another class to your object, and want to inject a class between Foo and Bar (for testing or some other reason):

```
class InjectMe(SomeBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        print('InjectMe.__init__(self) called')
        super().__init__()

class UnsuperInjector(UnsuperChild, InjectMe): pass

class SuperInjector(SuperChild, InjectMe): pass
```

Using the un-super child fails to inject the dependency because the child you're using has hard-coded the method to be called after its own:

```
>>> o = UnsuperInjector()
UnsuperChild.__init__(self) called
SomeBaseClass.__init__(self) called
```

However, the class with the child that uses `super` can correctly inject the dependency:

```
>>> o2 = SuperInjector()
SuperChild.__init__(self) called
InjectMe.__init__(self) called
SomeBaseClass.__init__(self) called
```

#### Addressing a comment

> Why in the world would this be useful?

Python linearizes a complicated inheritance tree via the [C3 linearization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) to create a Method Resolution Order (MRO).

We want methods to be looked up *in that order*.

For a method defined in a parent to find the next one in that order without `super`, it would have to

1. get the mro from the instance's type
2. look for the type that defines the method
3. find the next type with the method
4. bind that method and call it with the expected arguments

> The `UnsuperChild` should not have access to `InjectMe`. Why isn't the conclusion "Always avoid using `super`"? What am I missing here?

The `UnsuperChild` does *not* have access to `InjectMe`. It is the `UnsuperInjector` that has access to `InjectMe` - and yet cannot call that class's method from the method it inherits from `UnsuperChild`.

Both Child classes intend to call a method by the same name that comes next in the MRO, which might be *another* class it was not aware of when it was created.

The one without `super` hard-codes its parent's method - thus is has restricted the behavior of its method, and subclasses cannot inject functionality in the call chain.

The one *with* `super` has greater flexibility. The call chain for the methods can be intercepted and functionality injected.

You may not need that functionality, but subclassers of your code may.

### Conclusion

Always use `super` to reference the parent class instead of hard-coding it.

What you intend is to reference the parent class that is next-in-line, not specifically the one you see the child inheriting from.

Not using `super` can put unnecessary constraints on users of your code.

Comment: In C, DI is like [this](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/blob/master/code_Sedgewick/design2Code/listDesign.png). code is [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/tree/master/code_Sedgewick/design2Code/list).  If I add one more implementation of `list` interface, say `doublylinkedlist` then the application smoothly picks it. I can make my example more configurable by introducing `config.txt` and link implementation at load time. Is this the right example? If yes,How do I relate your code? See the first adv of DI in wiki. Where is any new implementation configurable? in your code

Comment: A new implementation is created through inheritance, for example, where one of the "Injector" classes inherits from the `InjectMe` class. Comments aren't for discussion, however, so I suggest you discuss this further with others in chat or ask a new question on the main site.

Comment: great answer! but when using multiple inheritance, there are complications with super() and `__init__` functions. especially if the signature of `__init__` varies between classes in the hierarchy. I've added an answer that focuses on this aspect

Comment: Thank you for this super()-verbose answer! I could not find anywhere else how the second argument is deduced in the Python 3 syntax (i.e. “moving up in the stack frame and getting the first argument to the method”). Seems strange they settled with this implicit syntax: less typing but somewhat inconsistent with the way things are done elsewhere within the class code where you need to always specify `self` explicitly (e.g. no implicit object-variable resolution).

Comment: @RomanShapovalov I recall doing the research on that, but I don't exactly recall where I found it - I think in the super object definition (written in C) in the source code. I would start there if you're looking to verify that the mechanism remains the same. However the mechanism works, it would still be an implementation detail that you're not expected to look at too closely, regardless...

Answer (score 61):

I had played a bit with `super()`, and had recognized that we can change calling order.

For example, we have next hierarchy structure:

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
   \ /
    D
```

In this case [MRO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848647) of D will be (only for Python 3):

```
In [26]: D.__mro__
Out[26]: (__main__.D, __main__.B, __main__.C, __main__.A, object)
```

Let's create a class where `super()` calls after method execution.

```
In [23]: class A(object): #  or with Python 3 can define class A:
...:     def __init__(self):
...:         print("I'm from A")
...:  
...: class B(A):
...:      def __init__(self):
...:          print("I'm from B")
...:          super().__init__()
...:   
...: class C(A):
...:      def __init__(self):
...:          print("I'm from C")
...:          super().__init__()
...:  
...: class D(B, C):
...:      def __init__(self):
...:          print("I'm from D")
...:          super().__init__()
...: d = D()
...:
I'm from D
I'm from B
I'm from C
I'm from A

    A
   / ⇖
  B ⇒ C
   ⇖ /
    D
```

So we can see that resolution order is same as in MRO. But when we call `super()` in the beginning of the method:

```
In [21]: class A(object):  # or class A:
...:     def __init__(self):
...:         print("I'm from A")
...:  
...: class B(A):
...:      def __init__(self):
...:          super().__init__()  # or super(B, self).__init_()
...:          print("I'm from B")
...:   
...: class C(A):
...:      def __init__(self):
...:          super().__init__()
...:          print("I'm from C")
...:  
...: class D(B, C):
...:      def __init__(self):
...:          super().__init__()
...:          print("I'm from D")
...: d = D()
...: 
I'm from A
I'm from C
I'm from B
I'm from D
```

We have a different order it is reversed a order of the MRO tuple.

```
    A
   / ⇘
  B ⇐ C
   ⇘ /
    D
```

For additional reading I would recommend next answers:

1. [C3 linearization example with super (a large hierarchy)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27670178)
2. [Important behavior changes between old and new style classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19950198/1322168)
3. [The Inside Story on New-Style Classes](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/inside-story-on-new-style-classes.html)

Comment: I dont understand why the order is changing. The first part I understand that D-B-C-A because D is the first class, then when load the self(B,C) will eventually print B, C then only A since B(A),C(A) pointed back to self for the final part. If I follow this understanding, then shouldnt the second part be like B-C-A-D? Could you please explain a little to me please.

Comment: My bad, I didnt notice that every each class instance has been initiated with super() first. Then if that is the case, shouldnt it be A-B-C-D? I somehow understand how A-C-B-D came to but still couldnt convince and still have a bit confuse. my understanding is that, d = D() called the Class D(B,C) with 2 self-parameters, since super() is initiated first then B is called together with it's attributes then D is not printed before C is because Class D(B,C) contains 2 self-parameters so it must execute the second one which is Class C(A), after executed there is not more self-parameters to executed

Comment: then it will print C then print B and finally print D. Am I right?

Comment: It's very easy to understand the second one as long as you get the first one. It is just like a stack. you push the print'' into stack and do super(), when it's done the A, it starts to print things in that stack, so the order is reverse.

Comment: It is like a recursion. What it does in the second example, it calls all classes first, puts them in the queue (or stack) because super() is called first. Then when it gets to the base class, it executes the base class' print method and goes down to the next one in the queue (or in the stack as @grantsun said). And in the first example D's print() is called first that's why it prints "I'm from D" first and only then it goes to the next class where it again sees print() first and again only then calls super()

Answer (score 36):

Doesn't all of this assume that the base class is a new-style class?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("A.__init__()")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("B.__init__()")
        super(B, self).__init__()
```

Will not work in Python 2. `class A` must be new-style, i.e: `class A(object)`

Answer (score 27):

When calling `super()` to resolve to a parent's version of a classmethod, instance method, or staticmethod, we want to pass the current class whose scope we are in as the first argument, to indicate which parent's scope we're trying to resolve to, and as a second argument the object of interest to indicate which object we're trying to apply that scope to.

Consider a class hierarchy `A`, `B`, and `C` where each class is the parent of the one following it, and `a`, `b`, and `c` respective instances of each.

```
super(B, b) 
# resolves to the scope of B's parent i.e. A 
# and applies that scope to b, as if b was an instance of A

super(C, c) 
# resolves to the scope of C's parent i.e. B
# and applies that scope to c

super(B, c) 
# resolves to the scope of B's parent i.e. A 
# and applies that scope to c
```

### Using `super` with a staticmethod

e.g. using `super()` from within the `__new__()` method

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, *a, **kw):
        # ...
        # whatever you want to specialize or override here
        # ...

        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls, *a, **kw)
```

Explanation:

1- even though it's usual for `__new__()` to take as its first param a reference to the calling class, it is *not* implemented in Python as a classmethod, but rather a staticmethod. That is, a reference to a class has to be passed explicitly as the first argument when calling `__new__()` directly:

```
# if you defined this
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        pass

# calling this would raise a TypeError due to the missing argument
A.__new__()

# whereas this would be fine
A.__new__(A)
```

2- when calling `super()` to get to the parent class we pass the child class `A` as its first argument, then we pass a reference to the object of interest, in this case it's the class reference that was passed when `A.__new__(cls)` was called. In most cases it also happens to be a reference to the child class. In some situations it might not be, for instance in the case of multiple generation inheritances.

```
super(A, cls)
```

3- since as a general rule `__new__()` is a staticmethod, `super(A, cls).__new__` will also return a staticmethod and needs to be supplied all arguments explicitly, including the reference to the object of insterest, in this case `cls`.

```
super(A, cls).__new__(cls, *a, **kw)
```

4- doing the same thing without `super`

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, *a, **kw):
        # ...
        # whatever you want to specialize or override here
        # ...

        return object.__new__(cls, *a, **kw)
```

### Using `super` with an instance method

e.g. using `super()` from within `__init__()`

```
class A(object): 
    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        # ...
        # you make some changes here
        # ...

        super(A, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
```

Explanation:

1- `__init__` is an instance method, meaning that it takes as its first argument a reference to an instance. When called directly from the instance, the reference is passed implicitly, that is you don't need to specify it:

```
# you try calling `__init__()` from the class without specifying an instance
# and a TypeError is raised due to the expected but missing reference
A.__init__() # TypeError ...

# you create an instance
a = A()

# you call `__init__()` from that instance and it works
a.__init__()

# you can also call `__init__()` with the class and explicitly pass the instance 
A.__init__(a)
```

2- when calling `super()` within `__init__()` we pass the child class as the first argument and the object of interest as a second argument, which in general is a reference to an instance of the child class.

```
super(A, self)
```

3- The call `super(A, self)` returns a proxy that will resolve the scope and apply it to `self` as if it's now an instance of the parent class. Let's call that proxy `s`. Since `__init__()` is an instance method the call `s.__init__(...)` will implicitly pass a reference of `self` as the first argument to the parent's `__init__()`.

4- to do the same without `super` we need to pass a reference to an instance explicitly to the parent's version of `__init__()`.

```
class A(object): 
    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        # ...
        # you make some changes here
        # ...

        object.__init__(self, *a, **kw)
```

### Using `super` with a classmethod

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def alternate_constructor(cls, *a, **kw):
        print "A.alternate_constructor called"
        return cls(*a, **kw)

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def alternate_constructor(cls, *a, **kw):
        # ...
        # whatever you want to specialize or override here
        # ...

        print "B.alternate_constructor called"
        return super(B, cls).alternate_constructor(*a, **kw)
```

Explanation:

1- A classmethod can be called from the class directly and takes as its first parameter a reference to the class.

```
# calling directly from the class is fine,
# a reference to the class is passed implicitly
a = A.alternate_constructor()
b = B.alternate_constructor()
```

2- when calling `super()` within a classmethod to resolve to its parent's version of it, we want to pass the current child class as the first argument to indicate which parent's scope we're trying to resolve to, and the object of interest as the second argument to indicate which object we want to apply that scope to, which in general is a reference to the child class itself or one of its subclasses.

```
super(B, cls_or_subcls)
```

3- The call `super(B, cls)` resolves to the scope of `A` and applies it to `cls`. Since `alternate_constructor()` is a classmethod the call `super(B, cls).alternate_constructor(...)` will implicitly pass a reference of `cls` as the first argument to `A`'s version of `alternate_constructor()`

```
super(B, cls).alternate_constructor()
```

4- to do the same without using `super()` you would need to get a reference to the *unbound* version of `A.alternate_constructor()` (i.e. the explicit version of the function). Simply doing this would not work:

```
class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def alternate_constructor(cls, *a, **kw):
        # ...
        # whatever you want to specialize or override here
        # ...

        print "B.alternate_constructor called"
        return A.alternate_constructor(cls, *a, **kw)
```

The above would not work because the `A.alternate_constructor()` method takes an implicit reference to `A` as its first argument. The `cls` being passed here would be its second argument.

```
class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def alternate_constructor(cls, *a, **kw):
        # ...
        # whatever you want to specialize or override here
        # ...

        print "B.alternate_constructor called"
        # first we get a reference to the unbound 
        # `A.alternate_constructor` function 
        unbound_func = A.alternate_constructor.im_func
        # now we call it and pass our own `cls` as its first argument
        return unbound_func(cls, *a, **kw)
```

Comment: The first paragraph in your answer is amazing. I wish the official python docs would explain it that way. I now feel like I have a good grasp on super()

Answer (score 25):

### Super() in a nutshell

- Every Python instance has a class that created it.
- Every class in Python has a chain of ancestor classes.
- A method using super() delegates work to the next ancestor in the chain for the instance's class.

### Example

This small example covers all the interesting cases:

```
class A:
    def m(self):
        print('A')

class B(A):
    def m(self):
        print('B start')
        super().m()
        print('B end')
        
class C(A):
    def m(self):
        print('C start')
        super().m()
        print('C end')

class D(B, C):
    def m(self):
        print('D start')
        super().m()
        print('D end')
```

The exact order of calls is determined by the instance the method is called from:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> c = C()
>>> d = D()
```

For instance *a*, there is no super call:

```
>>> a.m()
A
```

For instance *b*, the ancestor chain is `B -> A -> object`:

```
>>> type(b).__mro__   
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)

>>> b.m()
B start
A
B end
```

For instance *c*, the ancestor chain is `C -> A -> object`:

```
>>> type(c).__mro__   
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)

>>> c.m()
C start
A
C end
```

For instance *d*, the ancestor chain is more interesting `D -> B -> C -> A -> object` (***mro*** stands for method resolution order) :

```
>>> type(d).__mro__
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)

>>> d.m()
D start
B start
C start
A
C end
B end
D end
```

### More information

Having answered the question of "What does super do in Python?", the next question is how to use it effectively.  See this [step-by-step tutorial](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) or this [45 minute video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo&t=847s).

Comment: If you wonder how the MRO is working (i.e. why the execution jumps from B to C instead of from B to A) check the accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64740117/how-method-resolution-order-mro-is-working-in-this-python-code.
Basically, the `super()` delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type. That is the `super()` call in B, delegates the call to C (the sibling of B) instead of A (the parent of B).

Comment: You have a typo in instance c example:
    `>>> b.m()` should be `>>>c.m()`

Answer (score 12):

Many great answers, but for visual learners:
Firstly lets explore with arguments to super, and then without.
[image: super inheritance tree example]

Imagine theres an instance `jack` created from the class `Jack`, who has the inheritance chain as shown in green in the picture. Calling:

`super(Jack, jack).method(...)`

will use the MRO (Method Resolution Order) of `jack` (its inheritance tree in a certain order), and will start searching from `Jack`. Why can one provide a parent class? Well if we start searching from the instance `jack`, it would find the instance method, the whole point is to find its parents method.

If one does not supply arguments to super, its like the first argument passed in is the class of `self`, and the second argument passed in is `self`. These are auto-calculated for you in Python3.

However say we dont want to use `Jack`'s method, instead of passing in `Jack`, we could of passed in `Jen` to start searching upwards for the method from `Jen`.

It searches one layer at a time (width not depth), e.g. if `Adam` and `Sue` both have the required method, the one from `Sue` will be found first.

If `Cain` and `Sue` both had the required method, `Cain`'s method would be called first.
This corresponds in code to:

```
Class Jen(Cain, Sue):
```

MRO is from left to right.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of multiple inheritance, you normally want to call the initializers of both parents, not just the first. Instead of always using the base class, super() finds the class that is next in Method Resolution Order (MRO), and returns the current object as an instance of that class. For example:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("initializing Base")

class ChildA(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print("initializing ChildA")
        Base.__init__(self)

class ChildB(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print("initializing ChildB")
        super().__init__()

class Grandchild(ChildA, ChildB):
    def __init__(self):
        print("initializing Grandchild")
        super().__init__()
        
Grandchild()
```

results in

```
initializing Grandchild
initializing ChildA
initializing Base
```

Replacing `Base.__init__(self)` with `super().__init__()` results in

```
initializing Grandchild
initializing ChildA
initializing ChildB
initializing Base
```

as desired.

Answer (score 3):

some great answers here, but they do not tackle how to use `super()` in the case where different classes in the hierarchy have different signatures ... especially in the case of `__init__`

to answer that part and to be able to effectively use `super()` i'd suggest reading my answer [super() and changing the signature of cooperative methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56714419/super-and-changing-the-signature-of-cooperative-methods/56714809#56714809).

here's just the solution to this scenario:

> 1. the top-level classes in your hierarchy must inherit from a custom class like `SuperObject`:
> 2. if classes can take differing arguments, always pass all arguments you received on to the super function as keyword arguments, and, always accept `**kwargs`.

```py
class SuperObject:        
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print('SuperObject')
        mro = type(self).__mro__
        assert mro[-1] is object
        if mro[-2] is not SuperObject:
            raise TypeError(
                'all top-level classes in this hierarchy must inherit from SuperObject',
                'the last class in the MRO should be SuperObject',
                f'mro={[cls.__name__ for cls in mro]}'
            )

        # super().__init__ is guaranteed to be object.__init__        
        init = super().__init__
        init()
```

example usage:

```py
class A(SuperObject):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("A")
        super(A, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class B(SuperObject):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("B")
        super(B, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, age, **kwargs):
        print("C",f"age={age}")
        super(C, self).__init__(age=age, **kwargs)

class D(B):
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        print("D", f"name={name}")
        super(D, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)

class E(C,D):
    def __init__(self, name, age, *args, **kwargs):
        print( "E", f"name={name}", f"age={age}")
        super(E, self).__init__(name=name, age=age, *args, **kwargs)

E(name='python', age=28)
```

output:

```
E name=python age=28
C age=28
A
D name=python
B
SuperObject
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code:

```py
class X():
    def __init__(self):
        print("X")

class Y(X):
    def __init__(self):
        # X.__init__(self)
        super(Y, self).__init__()
        print("Y")

class P(X):
    def __init__(self):
        super(P, self).__init__()
        print("P")

class Q(Y, P):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Q, self).__init__()
        print("Q")

Q()
```

If change constructor of `Y` to `X.__init__`, you will get:

```
X
Y
Q
```

But using `super(Y, self).__init__()`, you will get:

```
X
P
Y
Q
```

And `P` or `Q` may even be involved from another file which you don't know when you writing `X` and `Y`. So, basically, you won't know what `super(Child, self)` will reference to when you are writing `class Y(X)`, even the signature of Y is as simple as `Y(X)`. That's why super could be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Child(SomeBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        SomeBaseClass.__init__(self)
```

This is fairly easy to understand.

```
class Child(SomeBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
```

Ok, what happens now if you use `super(Child,self)`?

When a Child instance is created, its MRO(Method Resolution Order) is in the order of (Child, SomeBaseClass, object) based on the inheritance. (assume SomeBaseClass doesn't have other parents except for the default object)

By passing `Child, self`,  `super` searches in the MRO of the `self` instance, and return the proxy object next of Child, in this case it's SomeBaseClass, this object then invokes the `__init__` method of SomeBaseClass. In other word, if it's `super(SomeBaseClass,self)`, the proxy object that `super` returns would be `object`

For multi inheritance, the MRO could contain many classes, so basically `super` lets you decide where you want to start searching in the MRO.