# Python: the mechanism behind list comprehension

Tags: python, implementation, list-comprehension, language-implementation

When using list comprehension or the `in` keyword in a for loop context, i.e:

```
for o in X:
    do_something_with(o)
```

or

```
l=[o for o in X]
```

- How does the mechanism behind `in` works?
- Which functions\methods within `X` does it call?
- If `X` can comply to more than one method, what's the precedence?
- How to write an efficient `X`, so that list comprehension will be quick?

Comment: Note that the "in" keyword is used in two distinct contexts in Python.  There are iterations (with the "for" keyboard) and there are boolean/conditional contexts (sometimes with "if" or "while"). The latter calls on the __contains__ methods for its objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The, afaik, complete and correct answer.

`for`, both in for loops and list comprehensions, calls `iter()` on `X`. `iter()` will return an iterable if `X` either has an `__iter__` method or a `__getitem__` method. If it implements both, `__iter__` is used. If it has neither you get `TypeError: 'Nothing' object is not iterable`.

This implements a `__getitem__`:

```
class GetItem(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __getitem__(self, x):
        return self.data[x]
```

Usage:

```
>>> data = range(10)
>>> print [x*x for x in GetItem(data)]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

This is an example of implementing `__iter__`:

```
class TheIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.index = -1

    # Note: In  Python 3 this is called __next__
    def next(self):
        self.index += 1
        try:
            return self.data[self.index]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

class Iter(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __iter__(self):
        return TheIterator(data)
```

Usage:

```
>>> data = range(10)
>>> print [x*x for x in Iter(data)]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

As you see you need both to implement an iterator, and `__iter__` that returns the iterator.

You can combine them:

```
class CombinedIter(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __iter__(self):
        self.index = -1
        return self

    def next(self):
        self.index += 1
        try:
            return self.data[self.index]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
```

Usage:

```
>>> well, you get it, it's all the same...
```

But then you can only have one iterator going at once.
OK, in this case you could just do this:

```
class CheatIter(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.data)
```

But that's cheating because you are just reusing the `__iter__` method of `list`.
An easier way is to use yield, and make `__iter__` into a generator:

```
class Generator(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __iter__(self):
        for x in self.data:
            yield x
```

**This last is the way I would recommend. Easy and efficient.**

Comment: +1 Great, comprehensive answer. Thanks for all the comments, too.

Answer (score 5):

`X` must be iterable. It must implement `__iter__()` which returns an iterator object; the iterator object must implement `next()`, which returns next item every time it is called or raises a `StopIteration` if there's no next item.

Lists, tuples and generators are all iterable.

Note that the plain `for` operator uses the same mechanism.

Comment: Iterators also have to implement `__iter__()`, though they can just return a reference to themselves

Comment: Right, generators do just that.

Comment: X can implement `__getitem__` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Answering question's comments I can say that reading source is not the best idea in this case. The code that is responsible for execution of compiled code ([ceval.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Python/ceval.c?view=markup)) does not seem to be very verbose for a person that sees Python sources for the first time. Here is the snippet that represents iteration in for loops:

```
   TARGET(FOR_ITER)
        /* before: [iter]; after: [iter, iter()] *or* [] */
        v = TOP();

        /*
          Here tp_iternext corresponds to next() in Python
        */
        x = (*v->ob_type->tp_iternext)(v); 
        if (x != NULL) {
            PUSH(x);
            PREDICT(STORE_FAST);
            PREDICT(UNPACK_SEQUENCE);
            DISPATCH();
        }
        if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
            if (!PyErr_ExceptionMatches(
                            PyExc_StopIteration))
                break;
            PyErr_Clear();
        }
        /* iterator ended normally */
        x = v = POP();
        Py_DECREF(v);
        JUMPBY(oparg);
        DISPATCH();
```

To find what actually happens here you need to dive into bunch of other files which verbosity is not much better. Thus I think that in such cases documentation and sites like SO are the first place to go while the source should be checked only for uncovered implementation details.

Answer (score 3):

`X` must be an iterable object, meaning it needs to have an `__iter__()` method.

So, to start a `for..in` loop, or a list comprehension, first `X`'s `__iter__()` method is called to obtain an iterator object; then that object's `next()` method is called for each iteration until `StopIteration` is raised, at which point the iteration stops.

I'm not sure what your third question means, and how to provide a meaningful answer to your fourth question except that your iterator should not construct the entire list in memory at once.

Comment: No, it needs to have `__iter__()` or `__geitem__()`.

Comment: @Lennart: Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps (tutorial http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html Section 9.9):

> Behind the scenes, the for statement
>   calls iter() on the container object.
>   The function returns an iterator
>   object that defines the method next()
>   which accesses elements in the
>   container one at a time. When there
>   are no more elements, next() raises a
>   StopIteration exception which tells
>   the for loop to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

How does the mechanism behind in works?

It is the exact same mechanism as used for ordinary for loops, as others have already noted.

Which functions\methods within X does it call?

As noted in a comment below, it calls `iter(X)` to get an iterator.  If `X` has a method function `__iter__()` defined, this will be called to return an iterator; otherwise, if `X` defines `__getitem__()`, this will be called repeatedly to iterate over `X`.  See the Python documentation for `iter()` here: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter

If X can comply to more than one method, what's the precedence?

I'm not sure what your question is here, exactly, but Python has standard rules for how it resolves method names, and they are followed here.  Here is a discussion of this:

[Method Resolution Order (MRO) in new style Python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-python-classes)

How to write an efficient X, so that list comprehension will be quick?

I suggest you read up more on iterators and generators in Python.  One easy way to make any class support iteration is to make a generator function for **iter**().  Here is a discussion of generators:

http://linuxgazette.net/100/pramode.html

Comment: Not really, it calls `iter()` which calls `__iter__()` or returns an iterator that uses `__getitem__`.