# How does the order of mixins affect the derived class?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views, method-resolution-order

Say, I have the following mixins that overlaps with each other by touching `dispatch()`:

```
class FooMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # perform check A
        ...
        return super(FooMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

class BarMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # perform check B
        ...
        return super(FooMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

If I want my view to go through the order, check A -> check B, should my code be `MyView(FooMixin, BarMixin, View)` or `MyView(BarMixin, FooMixin, View)`?

And why do we always put `View` or its subclasses after mixins? (I have noticed this from reading the source code of the django generic views, but I don't know the rationale behind it, if any)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The MRO is basically depth-first, left-to-right. See [Method Resolution Order (MRO) in new style Python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-python-classes) for some more info.

You can look at the [`__mro__` attribute](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) of the class to check, but `FooMixin` should be first if you want to do "check A" first.

```
class UltimateBase(object):
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'base dispatch'

class FooMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'perform check A'
        return super(FooMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

class BarMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'perform check B'
        return super(BarMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

class FooBar(FooMixin, BarMixin, UltimateBase):
    pass

FooBar().dispatch()
```

Prints:

```
perform check A
perform check B
base dispatch
```

`View` has to be last so that it "catches" any attribute lookups that weren't on any mixins, without hiding any methods on those mixins. I'm not sure I understand that part of your question -- what it "why is it added at all" or "why is it added last"?

Comment: thx agf. My question was meant to be "why is it added to the last" and you have answered it. Cheers.

Comment: Just to be clear, the only method that this calls directly is `FooMixin.dispatch`. `super(FooMixin, self).dispatch` then evaluates to `BarMixin.dispatch` because `object` does not have a `dispatch` method. `super(BarMixin, self).dispatch` evaluates to `UltimateBase.dispatch` for the same reason.

Comment: @MadPhysicist That's not quite right. This will work even if the method is one also defined by object -- try it yourself. See the linked answer for more information.

Comment: @agf. Of course. My mistake. `object`'s dispatch would be called last. My statement was really supposed to be a question but I got distracted and forgot to make that explicit. Thanks for answering anyway :)