# python diamond inheritance and the use of super() in the parents of the derived class

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiple-inheritance

First of all, I have to apologize for not having a better title. Feel free to change it if you find a more appropriate one.

Basically, I have been bugged by the behaviour of Python's multiple inheritance. In my [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018757/how-does-the-order-of-mixins-affect-the-derived-class), I got directed to read [Python's C3 MRO](http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.3/mro/). That really helps me to have a better understanding of multiple inheritance in Python. Just when I thought I got the grasp of it, I bumped into the following scenario, which I can't seem to make sense of.

```
class UltimateBase(object):
    def check(self):
        print 'base check'

class AMixin1(UltimateBase):
    def check(self):
        print 'check A'

class BMixin1(UltimateBase):
    def check(self):
        print 'check B'

class CMixin1(UltimateBase):
    def check(self):
        print 'check C'

class AMixin2(UltimateBase):
    def check(self):
        print 'check A'
        return super(AMixin2, self).check()

class BMixin2(UltimateBase):
    def check(self):
        print 'check B'
        return super(BMixin2, self).check()

class CMixin2(UltimateBase):
    def check(self):
        print 'check C'
        return super(CMixin2, self).check()

class MyView1(AMixin1, BMixin1, CMixin1):
    pass

class MyView2(AMixin2, BMixin2, CMixin2):
    pass

class MyView3(AMixin1, BMixin2, CMixin2):
    pass

class MyView4(AMixin2, BMixin1, CMixin2):
    pass

class MyView5(AMixin2, BMixin2, CMixin1):
    pass

class MyView6(AMixin1, BMixin1, CMixin2):
    pass

class MyView7(AMixin1, BMixin2, CMixin1):
    pass

class MyView8(AMixin2, BMixin1, CMixin1):
    pass

myview1 = MyView1()
myview2 = MyView2()
myview3 = MyView3()
myview4 = MyView4()
myview5 = MyView5()
myview6 = MyView6()
myview7 = MyView7()
myview8 = MyView8()

myview1.check()
print '------------------------'
myview2.check()
print '------------------------'
myview3.check()
print '------------------------'
myview4.check()
print '------------------------'
myview5.check()
print '------------------------'
myview6.check()
print '------------------------'
myview7.check()
print '------------------------'
myview8.check()
print '------------------------'
```

Outputs:

```
check A
------------------------
check A
check B
check C
base check
------------------------
check A
------------------------
check A
check B
------------------------
check A
check B
check C
------------------------
check A
------------------------
check A
------------------------
check A
check B
------------------------
```

I can trace out a pattern based on observing the outputs, but it bugs me not understanding the rationale behind this result.

I have questions like, for example, why does `myview2.check()` return

```
check A
check B
check C
base check
```

not

```
check A
base check
```

It seems to me that I am missing a key piece about multiple inheritance. Please fill in the gap for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `myview2.check()`, it traverses siblings then calls the base class.  Whenever one of those traversals hits `AMixin1`, `BMixin1`, or `CMixin1`, it stops, because those classes do not call `super(..., self).check()`.

As Benn points out, this is described in the [official Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super).  And if you think about it, it pretty much has to work this way.  Subclasses are going to assume the base class method isn't called before the subclass calls `super()`.  If it is (or, worse, if it depends on the order its siblings are listed), it makes things very difficult to deal with.

Comment: Thanks Chris. This is rather counter-intuitive. From the look of the result, the `check()` of the common ancestor doesn't get called unless all the parents call `super()`. Are there any literature that talk about this?

Comment: Instead of adding another answer that says mostly the same thing, I'll just link the documentation of `super()`, which is doing the magic in this case: [Official Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super).  The key there is that it will call parents _or siblings_ of `type` for cooperative multiple inheritance.

Comment: @Benn - That's exactly the last piece I need for my problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to get my head round the same question.
I found the following code helped simplify the issue:

(Basically, when all the `super`s have been hit for a class, that class gets called.)

```
class A:
  def f(self):
    print("............A: the common base of B and C")

class B(A):
  def f(self):
    print("........B: the left base of D")
    super().f()

class C(A):
  def f(self):
    print("........C: the right base of D")
    super().f()

class D(B,C):
  def f(self):
    print("....D: the top class")
    super().f()

d = D()

d.f()
```

Output:

```
....D: the top class
........B: the left base of D
........C: the right base of D
............A: the common base of B and C
```

[Try Online](https://repl.it/LFiI/0)