# Call resolution order in Python with multiple inheritance

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I was watching a Python talk at [Youtube](https://youtu.be/EiOglTERPEo?t=1147) and found an interesting language feature. However when I tried to run a test code it didn't work and I'd like to understand why.

I was expecting this to print this:

```
Parent
OtherParent
```

But instead I got this:

```
Parent
Parent
```

Sample code:

```
class Parent:
    def get_message(self):
        return "Parent"

class Child(Parent):
    def do_print(self):
        print(super().get_message())

class OtherParent:
    def get_message(self):
        return "OtherParent"

class OtherChild(Child, OtherParent):
    pass

Child().do_print()
OtherChild().do_print()
```

Edit: Running on Windows, Python 3.5.1, Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: `print(OtherChild.__mro__)` should answer your question

Comment: +1 on the `__mro__` explaining the behavior. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10018792/426790) for an answer about the order of mixins affecting OtherChild (short answer: "The MRO is basically depth-first, left-to-right").

Comment: Also, [here](http://blog.codekills.net/2014/04/02/the-sadness-of-pythons-super/)'s an article talking about the possible confusion of using `super()` and mixins at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct explanation is mentioned in the comments of the question, ie from MRO of the `OtherChild` class (link posted in the comment: [How does the order of mixins affect the derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018757/how-does-the-order-of-mixins-affect-the-derived-class/10018792#10018792)).

See the different outputs of the MRO of the `OtherChild` class depending on the different inheritances:

1. `OtherParent` have no parent class:

   ```
   class OtherParent():
       def get_message(self):
           return "OtherParent"

   print(OtherChild.__mro__)
   Child().do_print()
   OtherChild().do_print()
   ```

   Output shows that `Parent` comes before `OtherParent`:

   ```
   (<class '__main__.OtherChild'>, <class '__main__.Child'>, <class '__main__.Parent'>, <class '__main__.OtherParent'>, <class 'object'>)
   Parent
   Parent
   ```
2. `Parent` is the parent class of `OtherParent`:

   ```
   class OtherParent(Parent):
       def get_message(self):
           return "OtherParent"
   ```

   Output shows that `OtherParent` comes now before `Parent`:

   ```
   (<class '__main__.OtherChild'>, <class '__main__.Child'>, <class '__main__.OtherParent'>, <class '__main__.Parent'>, <class 'object'>)
   Parent
   OtherParent
   ```
3. Still case 2 but now OtherChild inherits first from `OtherParent`, then `Child`:

   ```
   class OtherParent(Parent):
       def get_message(self):
           return "OtherParent"

   class OtherChild(OtherParent, Child):
       pass
   ```

   Output shows that `OtherParent` comes again before `Parent`, but before `Child` too:

   ```
   (<class '__main__.OtherChild'>, <class '__main__.OtherParent'>, <class '__main__.Child'>, <class '__main__.Parent'>, <class 'object'>)
   Parent
   Parent
   ```

Maybe someone can explain the last case which is not natural at first look.

Comment: Neither parent has `do_print`, it is only defined in the `Child` class, did you mean `get_message`? But even then I don't quite follow the explanation.

Comment: @NikoNyrh then *why did you accept it?!* Perhaps it would be better to delete this question entirely (you will need to unaccept and unvote this answer), read the linked question on MRO order then ask again if you're still uncertain. As it stands, this whole thing is a car wreck.

Comment: Sorry I was too eager to accept a plausible looking answer before reading it in detail :/ I cannot delete the question as it already has answers. Next time I'll do more research before asking the question.

Comment: @NikoNyrh I updated my edit to add some exemples with the good explanation (I hope :))

Answer (score -2):

Ah my friend pointed out to a small deviation from the example on Youtube:

```
class Parent:
    def get_message(self):
        return "Parent"

class Child(Parent):
    def do_print(self):
        print(super().get_message())

class OtherParent(Parent): # <----- Inheritance of Parent makes it work
    def get_message(self):
        return "OtherParent"

class OtherChild(Child, OtherParent):
    pass

Child().do_print()
OtherChild().do_print()
```

Comment: This doesn't really explain *why* the first code doesn't work as expected, or how this change fixes it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know inner workings of Python to know the answer in detail.

Comment: Oh, you're the OP - then you could add this to the question, rather than posting it as an answer: *"it works as expected if I make `OtherParent` inherit from `Parent`, but I don't understand why"*

Comment: True, although my question was more on "why doesn't this code work as advertised" and the answer was I didn't implement it properly. In hindsight I might as well have deleted the question.

Comment: But if you don't understand the difference, *why* adding that inheritance alters the behaviour, then you may still have a question.