# Django: DRY principle and UserPassesTestMixin

Tags: python, django, generics

I have a model named `Post` and have a field there called `owner` (foreign key to `User`). Of course, only owners can `update` or `delete` their own posts.

That being said, I use `login_required` decorator in the views to make sure the user is logged in but then, I also need to make sure the user trying to `update`/`delete` the question is the `owner`.

As I'm using [Django: Generic Editing Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/) the documentation says I need to use [Django: UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin).

This validation will be done for the `update` and `delete` views. DRY, what is the way to go about this? should I create a class named `TestUserOwnerOfPost` and create a `test_func()` and then make the `update` and `delete` views inherit from it?

Cause that's what I have tried and didn't work, code below:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class TestUserOwnerOfPost(UserPassesTestMixin):                         
    def test_func(self):                                                       
        return self.request.user == self.post.owner

class EditPost(UpdateView, TestUserOwnerOfPost):                         
    model = Post                                                                         
    @method_decorator(login_required)                                          
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):                                       
        return super(EditPost, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

With the code above, every logged-in user in the system can `edit`/`delete` any post. What am I doing wrong? am I missing something? thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first problem is that the order of the classes you inherit is incorrect, as @rafalmp says.

However, fixing that doesn't solve the problem, because the `UserPassesTest` mixin performs the test *before* running the view. This means that it's not really suitable to check the owner of `self.object`, because `self.object` has not been set yet. Note I'm using `self.object` instead of `self.post` -- I'm don't think that the view ever sets `self.post` but I might be wrong about that.

One option is to call `self.get_object()` inside the test function. This is a bit inefficient because your view will fetch the object twice, but in practice it probably doesn't matter.

```
def test_func(self):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    return self.request.user == self.object.owner
```

Another approach is to override `get_queryset`, to restrict it to objects owned by the user. This means the user will get a 404 error if they do not own the object. This behaviour is not exactly the same as the `UserPassesTestMixin`, which will redirect to a login page, but it might be ok for you.

```
class OwnerQuerysetMixin(object):                         
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(OwnerQuerysetMixin, self).get_queryset()                                                   
        # perhaps handle the case where user is not authenticated
        queryset = queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)
        return queryset
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your extended explanation. And to me makes sense to restrict the objects to the ones owned by the user. Just one quick question, for this to work I need to inherit `OwnerQuerysetMixin` before `UpdateView`. Why is that? I thought `get_queryset` was a method from `UpdateView` and should be overwritten by  the one in `OwnerQuerysetMixin`, with that line of thought, to me (pardon me if I'm missing something) makes more sense to inherit `OwnerQuerysetMixin` after `UpdateView`. Sigh, I just want to be clear about how the inheritance thing works in here.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018757/how-does-the-order-of-mixins-affect-the-derived-class) might help you understand the ordering.

Answer (score 3):

The order of the classes you inherit from matters. For your access control to work, it must be enforced before UpdateView is executed:

```
class EditPost(TestUserOwnerOfPost, UpdateView):
```

Comment: Indeed, but then I get a `'AttributeError: EditPost' object has no attribute 'post'` :/

Comment: Well, I actually get this is because UpdateView is the object that actually gets the object `post` and your way I'm importing `TestUserOwnerOfPost` first. The thing is, how can I accomplish my validation?