# Python's super() working?

Tags: python

I have a program something like this :

```
class A():
    def go(self):
        print("A")


class B(A):
    def go(self):
        super().go()
        print("B")


class C(A):
    def go(self):
        super().go()
        print("C")


class D(A):
    def go(self):
        super().go()
        print("D")


class E(B, C, D):
    def go(self):
        super().go()
        print("E")


a  = A()
b = B()
c = C()
d = D()
e = E()

print(e.go())
```

Here is the output to this:

```
A
D
C
B
E
None
```

I was curious about the workflow of super(), how does it print D, C before B and why is None printed at last? A detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you read any of the numerous existing resources on this? For example, http://stackoverflow.com/q/3277367/3001761. What specifically do you still not understand?

Comment: @cricket_007 because it's next in the MRO after A, that's why you put mix-ins before the actual base class (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10018757/3001761).

Comment: See Raymond Hettinger's excellent blog post, Super Considered Super, https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ and the talk from PyCon 2015: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo. You see the order D, C, B because that is how Python's Method Resolution Order (MRO) works.

Comment: @jon I missed that init wasn't defined and only e.go() is ran

Comment: I thought I understood how `super` worked and then this question comes and proves me wrong. Time to avoid `super` like the plague _again_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `help(e)` you can see the [method resolution order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/):

```
>>> e = E()
>>> help(e)
class E(B, C, D)
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      E
 |      B
 |      C
 |      D
 |      A
 |      builtins.object
```

Since you first call `super` and then `print` the output will be exactly the reversed `mro`:

```
A -> D -> C -> B -> E
```

If you had the `print`s before the `super`-calls it would follow the MRO:

```
E -> B -> C -> D -> A
```

However the `E.go` doesn't return anything (`return None` is implicit if there's no other `return` before) so it will print `None` after all the methods have been called.

Comment: Yes, I understood the MRO part. But shouldn't B be printed after A, as B has completed it's super() call and now it should print its own part?

Comment: @AnmolGulati The MRO is always **linear** even if the inheritance is not linear. So when you use `super()` it's always along the MRO.

Comment: @AnmolGulati The thing is that python magically inserts `C` and `D` _between_ `B` and `A`. It's a terrible design choice IMO.

Comment: @Rawing Well, you could think it's a terrible design choice but this way you get "dependency injection" built into the basic inheritance. You don't need to rely on frameworks to handle it like in other languages. But it's sometimes confusing - I always need to check the `help` to figure out if the inheritance is working as intended as well :) If you don't want to be confused: avoid multiple inheritance - single inheritance is easy to understand.

Comment: @MSeifert Can you explain a bit further, please? Thanks.

Comment: @MSeifert --> "The MRO is always linear even if the inheritance is not linear. So when you use super() it's always along the MRO". This part.

Comment: @AnmolGulati As soon as you call the method python looks at the MRO of the class you called. The MRO is then fixed - It won't look at the MRO of the individual classes. It only follows the MRO of the class you called the method on. And for diamond inheritance remember that the MRO is _roughly_: siblings first (`B`, `C` and `D`) - parents last (`A`).

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks :-)