# How do I combine Django's ‘LoginRequiredMixin’ and Form Tools' ‘FormPreview’?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-authentication

`LoginRequiredMixin` works great on other class based views. Also the Form Tools `FormPreview` works fine. But when I try to use both together, then the `LoginRequiredMixin` gets ignored.

This is even the case if I use the most basic example from [form tools](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/preview.html#how-to-use-formpreview) and the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Two things I found strange (but this does not necessary be the reason):

- "This mixin should be at the leftmost position in the inheritance list." This sounds like there is some internal hack that breaks if someone does something irregular. There is no explanation why.
- The Form Tools view should be called itself and not the method `.as_view()`, which is off standard again.

Is this a bug? What can I do?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018757/how-does-the-order-of-mixins-affect-the-derived-class) might help you understand why the mixin should be leftmost. It's not an internal hack -- you just want the login check to run *before* the view runs.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FormPreview` is not a generic class based view, so you can't use it with mixins like `LoginRequiredMixin`.

You can use the [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator when you include the form preview instance in your URL patterns:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

url_patterns = [
    url(r'^form-handler/$', login_required(MyFormPreview(SomeModelForm))),
]
```