# Django Custom User authentication, lookup error User not registered

Tags: python, django, django-cms

After running a migration I get the following error:

LookupError: Model 'users.UserProfile' not registered.

I am trying to create a customer User for Django-cms.  It just does not want to do it.

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\user\Envs\p37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\user\Envs\p37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
django.setup()
File "C:\Users\user\Envs\p37\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\user\Envs\p37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
app_config.import_models()
File "C:\Users\user\Envs\p37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "C:\Users\user\Envs\p37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\user\Envs\p37\lib\site-packages\djangocms_text_ckeditor\models.py", line 10, in <module>
from cms.models import CMSPlugin
File "C:\Users\user\Envs\p37\lib\site-packages\cms\models\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from .permissionmodels import *  # nopyflakes
File "C:\Users\user\Envs\p37\lib\site-packages\cms\models\permissionmodels.py", line 21, in <module>
User = apps.get_registered_model(user_app_name, user_model_name)
File "C:\Users\user\Envs\p37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 270, in get_registered_model
"Model '%s.%s' not registered." % (app_label, model_name))
LookupError: Model 'users.UserProfile' not registered.
```

Models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone
from .managers import UserProfileManager


class UserPlans(models.Model):
    plan = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_plan_choices_data(self):
        return UserPlans.objects.values_list('id', 'plan')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Plan'


class EnglishInterest(models.Model):
    english_interest = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_english_interest_data(self):
        return EnglishInterest.objects.values_list('id', 'english_interest')


class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    english_interest = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    plan_choice = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    english_interest = models.ForeignKey(
    EnglishInterest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='general speaking')
    plan = models.ForeignKey(
    UserPlans, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='monthly')
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['english_interest', 'plan_choice',
                   'first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'location']

    objects = UserProfileManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        # "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        # "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        # "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

Managers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

admin.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import EnglishInterest, UserPlans, UserProfile
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    ENGLISH_INTEREST = EnglishInterest().get_english_interest_data()
    PLAN_CHOICES = UserPlans().get_plan_choices_data()

    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=255, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                         'type': 'email', 'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'email', 'placeholder': 'Email', 'data-validetta': 'required,email'}))

    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'password', 'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'password1', 'placeholder': 'Password', 'data-validetta': 'required,minLength[4],maxLength[20]'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'password', 'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'password1', 'placeholder': 'Confirm Password', 'data-validetta': 'required,minLength[4],maxLength[20],equalTo[password1]'}))
    nextButton = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'button', 'name': 'next', 'class': 'next action-button', 'value': 'Next'}))

    english_interest = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=ENGLISH_INTEREST, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(
    attrs={'name': 'english_interest', 'data-validetta': 'minChecked[1],maxChecked[4]'}))
    plan_choices = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PLAN_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(
    attrs={'name': 'plan', 'data-validetta': 'minRadio[1]'}))
previousButton = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'button', 'name': 'previous', 'class': 'previous action-button', 'value': 'Previous'}))
nextButton2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'button', 'name': 'next2', 'class': 'next action-button', 'value': 'Next'}))

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'name': 'first_name', 'placeholder': 'First Name', 'data-validetta': 'required'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'name': 'last_name', 'placeholder': 'Last Name', 'data-validetta': 'required'}))
    age = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=2, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                         'type': 'number', 'name': 'age', 'placeholder': 'Age', 'data-validetta': 'required,minLength[1],maxLength[2],number'}))
    location = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'name': 'location', 'placeholder': 'Location', 'data-validetta': 'required'}))
    previousButton2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'button', 'name': 'previous2', 'class': 'previous action-button', 'value': 'Previous'}))
submitButton = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'submit', 'name': 'submit', 'class': 'submit action-button', 'value': 'Submit'}))

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'english_interest',
              'plan_choices', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'location')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'english_interest',
              'plan_choices', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'location', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserProfileForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
    ('Personal info', {'fields': ('age',)}),
    ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
)
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('email', 'age', 'password1', 'password2')}
     ),
)
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


admin.site.register(EnglishInterest)
admin.site.register(UserPlans)

# Now register the new UserAdmin...
admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserAdmin)
# ... and, since we're not using Django's built-in permissions,
# unregister the Group model from admin.
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

And yes, I do have in my settings.py:
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.UserProfile'

and in Installed apps my user app does come before cms:

```
INSTALLED_APPS[
    ...    
    'users',
    'cms',
     ...
]
```

Comment: Is 'users' also listed before 'django.contrib.auth' and 'django.contrib.admin'? It should be the top-most app in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Unreal, I can't believe that worked.  Now I'm getting a different error.

django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (is_admin, plan_choices, password2, password1) specified for UserProfile

Comment: The `fields` variable should only list fields that you want to take from your model `UserProfile`, not any custom field you're adding to your form. `is_admin`, `plan_choices`, `password1` and `password2` don't exist on `UserProfile` model.

Comment: Side note: `def has_perm(): return True` is not a good idea. You're allowing everyone to make changes to any model like that.

Comment: Just an observation, but your UserProfile class has the superclasses listed in reverse order. You probably want the Mixin class to come first, then the abstract class.  Like this:   `class UserProfile(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser)`

For more info see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018757/how-does-the-order-of-mixins-affect-the-derived-class)

Comment: I think I've got the fields sorted out now, but there is another error:

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1364, "Field 'name' doesn't have a default value")

seems to be originating from the query:

b"INSERT INTO `django_content_type` (`app_label`, `model`) VALUES ('admin', 'logentry')"