# python method resolution order and diamond inheritance

Tags: python

Here is an example model of what I have in my python code

```
class BasicActivity:
    def run(self):
        print "basic run"

    def jump(self):
        print "basic jump"

class ChickenStyleActivity(BasicActivity):
    def run(self):
        print "run like chicken"

class BunnyStyleActivity(BasicActivity):
    def jump(self):
        print "jump like bunny"

class ExtraordinaryActivity(ChickenStyleActivity,BunnyStyleActivity):
    pass

d = ExtraordinaryActivity()
d.run()
d.jump()
```

I was expecting to have both chicken and bunny styles in one class, but surprisingly for me it was chicken run but basic jump.
I started reading about method resolution order and now I can see that changing order of classes in multiple inheritance will bring the opposite effect.

The question is - how can I have both Chicken and Bunny styles in one class?

More generally: how to properly inherit several classes which have common base class when method overriding comes into play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're using Python 2.x, not Python 3.x.

Therefore BasicActivity needs to inherit from `object`:

```
class BasicActivity(object):
    pass
```

Alex Martelli describes it here:
[Method Resolution Order (MRO) in new style Python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-python-classes/1848647#1848647)

In Python 3 all classes inherit from `object`

Comment: for the sake of completeness: old-style classes (ones that don't inherit from object) use depth-first left-to-right method resolution order.

Comment: no, I'm using python2.7, but your solution works - I kept methods in Base class, just modified it to inherit from `object` and now I have both overridden versions in my top class. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't mean python2.0, I meant 2.x.

Comment: so in python 3 my sample would work without inheriting from `object`?

Comment: Exactly. Basically you shouldn't use old style classes in 2.7, because they are not forward-compatible.