# Python Multiple Inheritance - Call a method of a class, but which one?

Tags: python, object, multiple-inheritance

```
class MyClass(Class1, Class2):
    pass
```

Both parents have a `getImage` method.

```
thing = MyClass()
thing.getImage() #I want to call Class1's
thing.getImage() #I want to call Class2's
```

Which `getImage` gets called? How do I specify which one to call?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-python-classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `thing.getImage` will call `Class1.getImage` provided that it exists.  If you want to call the other, you can use the longer form:

```
Class2.getImage(thing)
```

These things can be inspected via the class's method resolution order (`__mro__`):

```
>>> class foo(object): pass
... 
>>> class bar(object): pass
... 
>>> class baz(foo,bar): pass
... 
>>> print baz.__mro__
(<class '__main__.baz'>, <class '__main__.foo'>, <class '__main__.bar'>, <type 'object'>)
```

This shows that `baz` is searched for the method first, then `foo`, then `bar` and finally `object`.

[Further reading about multiple inheritance](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance)

[Further reading about mro](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)