# Inheritance troubles. - Python

Tags: python, inheritance

Someone had this exact same problem on this site, but the answer didn't relate to the part I have trouble with.
Inheritance - Method Calls

Consider the following class definitions.

```
class C1(object):
    def f(self):
        return 2*self.g()

    def g(self):
        return 2

class C2(C1):
    def f(self):
        return 3*self.g()


class C3(C1):
    def g(self):
        return 5

class C4(C3):
    def f(self):
        return 7*self.g()

obj1 = C1()
obj2 = C2()
obj3 = C3()
obj4 = C4()
```

For this problem you are to consider which methods are called when the `f` method is called. So for example, when `obj1.f()` is called, the `f` method of `C1` is called which calls the `g` method of `C1`. This could be represented as a 'calling list' of the form

```
['C1.f', 'C1.g']
```

Write three assignment statements that, respectively, assigns the 'calling list' for `obj2.f()` to the variable `obj2_calls`, assigns the 'calling list' for `obj3.f()` to the variable `obj3_calls` and assigns the 'calling list' for `obj4.f()` to the variable `obj4_calls`.

I have no problem understanding the first assignment, it is `obj2_calls = ['C2.f', 'C1.g']`
but I am wracking my brain trying to figure out the next one. I thought since there is no `C3.f` that the list would be `['C1.f']` but unfortunately it's not.

Just to clear up, this IS homework

Comment: Add some `print` statements to each function to figure out what's really going on.

Comment: if you type in C3.f you'll see c3.f <unbound method C3.f> which means its a part of the class C3

Comment: Hi guys very helpful, using print I have the correct answer. But I used more common sense to get that than understanding of the code.

I'd still like to understand why the answer was 
obj3_calls = ['C1.f', 'C3.g'] . I don't get why 'c3.g' is called after 'c1.f'

Comment: Just to be certain I'm understanding the assignment correctly the proper answer is `['C1.f', 'C3.g']`, correct?

Comment: Yep, that's what I got

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with the method resolution order (MRO) of your class. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-python-classes) for some useful info)

As you stated correctly, there is no `C3.f` function, so python looks up the `f` method on the first base-class in the MRO that has `f` defined.  In this case, that is (`C1`).  Now, that method (`C1.f`) calls `self.g()`.  In this case `self` **is an instance of `C3`**, so of course, `self.g` calls `C3.g` since that is the highest `g` function in the MRO.  If you wanted to guarantee that you get `C1.g`, you'd need to do it explicitly:

```
class C1(object):
    def f(self):
        return 2*C1.g(self)
    def g(self):
        return 5
```

which also makes a nice lead-in to talking about double-underscore name mangling.  Since that is a separate topic though, maybe it's best to only leave a [link to some useful documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that, and to everyone for their help. I understand now

Answer (score 1):

obj3_calls is `['C1.f', 'C3.g']`. As you point out, there is no `C3.f` in that class, but this method is inherited from `C1`. This one in turn calls `self.g`, and since `C3.g` **is** defined, it overrides the method that is inherited from `C1`.