# Django Class Based View Inheritance Issue

Tags: python, django

I have two form classes, each of which are a ModelForm of the same model. One is called       `ProjectForm` and the other is called `AdminProjectForm`. `ProjectForm` has a number of fields excluded, `AdminProjectForm` does not.

In my views, I'm using two classes, `Edit` and `AdminEdit`. `Edit` uses the Django generic editing view of `UpdateView` and has the `form_class` set to `ProjectForm`. `AdminEdit` is a inherits `Edit` and has the `form_class` set to `AdminProjectEdit`.

One would think this would mean that the form generated by `AdminEdit` would thus show the fields that are excluded on `Edit`. This part is working correctly - the form fields are drawn perfectly fine (and not drawn on `Edit`. However, when submitting the `AdminEdit` form, any field excluded in `ProjectForm` is stripped and not saved. Any suggestions?

Here's my `forms.py`:

```
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        exclude = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3',     'qualifies_for_judging', 'reason_for_disqualification', 'finalist', 'hashtag')

class AdminProjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        exclude = ()
```

And my views.py:

```
class Edit(UpdateView):
    model = Project 
    form_class = ProjectForm

class AdminEdit(Edit):
    model = Project 
    form_class = AdminProjectForm
```

Comment: I have done similar things without the effects you describe. I would guess the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Why is `AdminEdit` inheriting from `Edit` and not `UpdateView`?

Comment: The inheritance chain is `AdminEdit -> Edit -> UpdateView`. But it stops at `Edit` since `Edit` fulfills each of AdminEdits requirements. It's related to the MRO of Python and newstyle classes. This could perhaps help you more -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-python-classes