# Python multiple inheritance unittest -

Tags: python, unit-testing, inheritance

I'm trying to understand what happens when doing multiple inheritance using a `unittest.TestCase` class.

`MyTest_DoesWork` outputs what I expect, this is both `setUp()` and `tearDown()` being triggered. This is not happening with `MyTest_DoesNotWork`. Why is this happening? Any clue?

```
import unittest

class MyClassTest1(object):
    def setUp(self):
        print 'Setting up', self.__class__
    def test_a1(self):
        print "Running test_a1 for class", self.__class__
    def test_a2(self):
        print "Running test_a2 for class", self.__class__
    def tearDown(self):
        print 'Tearing down', self.__class__

class MyClassTest2(object):
    def setUp(self):
        print 'Setting up', self.__class__
    def test_b1(self):
        print "Running test_b1 for class", self.__class__
    def test_b2(self):
        print "Running test_b2 for class", self.__class__
    def tearDown(self):
        print 'Tearing down', self.__class__

class MyTest_DoesNotWork(unittest.TestCase, MyClassTest1, MyClassTest2):
    """
    Output:
    Running test_a1 for class <class '__main__.MyTest_DoesNotWork'>
    .Running test_a2 for class <class '__main__.MyTest_DoesNotWork'>
    .Running test_b1 for class <class '__main__.MyTest_DoesNotWork'>
    .Running test_b2 for class <class '__main__.MyTest_DoesNotWork'>
    """
    pass

class MyTest_DoesWork(MyClassTest1, MyClassTest2, unittest.TestCase):
    """
    Output:
    Setting up <class '__main__.MyTest_DoesWork'>
    Running test_a1 for class <class '__main__.MyTest_DoesWork'>
    Tearing down <class '__main__.MyTest_DoesWork'>
    .Setting up <class '__main__.MyTest_DoesWork'>
    Running test_a2 for class <class '__main__.MyTest_DoesWork'>
    Tearing down <class '__main__.MyTest_DoesWork'>
    .Setting up <class '__main__.MyTest_DoesWork'>
    Running test_b1 for class <class '__main__.MyTest_DoesWork'>
    Tearing down <class '__main__.MyTest_DoesWork'>
    .Setting up <class '__main__.MyTest_DoesWork'>
    Running test_b2 for class <class '__main__.MyTest_DoesWork'>
    Tearing down <class '__main__.MyTest_DoesWork'>
    """
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Do you have those docstrings the wrong way round? Seems like __DoesNotWork is actually working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-python-classes, http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/

Answer (score 7):

Python's [method resolution order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) causes this.  With your inheritance structure, it is resolving in the order you declared the parent classes, left to right.

So with `MyTest_DoesNotWork`, python is going to hit the `unittest.TestCase` implementations of `setUp` and `tearDown`, which do not do anything.  Because `unittest.TestCase.setUp` is not written to be cooperative and call other superclass `setUp` methods, it just stops there and nothing gets printed.

With `MyTest_DoesWork`, python will instead resolve to `MyClassTest1` first.  Just like `unittest.TestCase`, you haven't written your `setUp` and `tearDown` methods to cooperatively call superclass methods.  So it stops there and never calls the `MyClassTest2` methods.  So I am guessing that even this actually isn't working as you expected.  Change your `MyClassTest1` `setUp` and `tearDown` methods to print out "MyClassTest1" instead of `self.class` and you will see that it's the one being called all the time.  `MyClassTest2` `setUp` and `tearDown` are never called.