# How does multiple inheritance work in descriptors?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I watched a great video on YouTube about Python metaprogramming. I tried to write the following code (which is almost the same from the video):

```
class Descriptor:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, val):
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = val

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        del instance.__dict__[self.name]

class Type(Descriptor):
    ty = object
    def __set__(self, instance, val):
        if not isinstance(val, self.ty):
            raise TypeError("%s should be of type %s" % (self.name, self.ty))
        super().__set__(instance, val)

class String(Type):
    ty = str

class Integer(Type):
    ty = int

class Positive(Descriptor):
    def __set__(self, instance, val):
        if val <= 0:
            raise ValueError("Must be > 0")
        super().__set__(instance, val)

class PositiveInteger(Integer, Positive):
    pass

class Person(metaclass=StructMeta):
    _fields = ['name', 'gender', 'age']
    name = String('name')
    gender = String('gender')
    age = PositiveInteger('age')
```

So `PositiveInteger` is inherited from `Integer` and `Positive`, and both classes have `__get__` method defined to do some validation. I wrote some test code to convince myself that both methods will run:

```
class A:
    def test(self):
        self.a = 'OK'

class B:
    def test(self):
        self.b = 'OK'

class C(A, B):
    pass

c = C()
c.test()
print(self.a)
print(self.b)
```

Only to find that only the first print statement works. The second will raise an AttributeError, which indicates that when there's name conflict, the first base class wins.

So I wonder why both validations work? It's even more weird that when only the Integer check passes (e.g. person.age = -3), it's `super().__set__(instance, val)` has no effect, leaving person.age untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation logic of both `Positive` and `Integer` runs because both `Type` and `Positive` have this line in `__set__`:

```
super().__set__(instance, val)
```

This doesn't skip to `Descriptor.__set__`. Instead, it calls the next method in [method resolution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-python-classes). `Type.__set__` gets called, and its `super().__set__(instance, val)` calls `Positive.__set__`. `Positive.__set__` runs its validation and calls `Descriptor.__set__`, which does the setting. This behavior is one of the reasons we have `super`.

If you wanted your `test` methods to behave like that, you would need to do two things. First, you would need to make `A` and `B` inherit from a common base class with a `test` method that doesn't do anything, so the `super` chains end at a place with a `test` method instead of going to `object`:

```
class Base:
    def test():
        pass
```

Then, you would need to add `super().test()` to both `A.test` and `B.test`:

```
class A(Base):
    def test(self):
        self.a = 'OK'
        super().test()

class B(Base):
    def test(self):
        self.b = 'OK'
        super().test()
```

For more reading, see [Python's super() considered super](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Comment: Thanks for your excellent explanation! I was posting my own answer and didn't know someone has already answered this question until I refreshed the page. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad.

The video gave perfect explanation just minute after where I paused and asked this question.

So when multiple inheritance happends, there's MRO thing (Method Resolution Order) defined in each class that determines the resolution order of methods in the `super()` chain.
The order is determined by depth-first search, e.g.

```
class A:
    pass
class B(A):
    pass
class C(B):
    pass
class D(A):
    pass
class E(C, D):
    pass
```

`E.__mro__` will be:

```
(<class '__main__.E'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

One thing to notice is that A will appear in the inheritance tree multiple times, and in the MRO list it will only be in the last place where all A's appear.

Here's the trick: the call to `super()` won't necessarily go to its base. Instead, it'll find in the MRO list what comes next.

So to explain what happens in the code:
The `super()` call in `Integer.__get__` (which is inherited from `Type.__get__`) won't go to `Descriptor.__get__`, because `Descriptor` appears last in the MRO list. It will fall into `Positive.__set__`, and then its `super()` will fall into `Descriptor`, which will eventually set the value of the attribute.