# python functions in Multiple inheritance

Tags: python

I'm learning python.I met a confused.

Here is ther first script A.py

```
#!/bin/env python

class A():
    def test(self):
        print("A.Func")

class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    def test(self):
        print("C.Func")

class D(B,C):
    pass

d = D()
d.test()
```

Result:A.Func

and another python script B.py

The difference between A.py and B.py is class A.

```
#!/bin/env python

class A(object):
    def test(self):
        print("A.Func")

class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    def test(self):
        print("C.Func")

class D(B,C):
    pass

d = D()
d.test()
```

Result:C.Func

Why?

Comment: Is this Python 2.x ?

Comment: definite duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-python-classes

Comment: Python version is 2.7.10