# Class Inheritence Naming in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

There is a BaseClient

```
class BaseClient(object):
```

that later get inherits in a lot of classes

```
class Account(BaseClient):

    def create(self, **params):
        pass
```

and few others.

```
class MainClass(Account, User):
    pass
```

There a few functions that use the same  create function

```
def create(self, **params):
        pass
```

How to add a unique class label like

```
MainClass.Account.create()
```

Now it is working as

```
MainClass.create()
```

Update:
There a lot duplicate functions like create() that going to override the ones that are inherting from. I would like to call the class like Account, so when I call

```
MainClass.Account.create()
MainClass.User.create()
```

they act so two different functions.

Comment: I fail to understand your question at all. Can you add more detail? I don’t even know where more detail is needed, because I really don’t understand what you’re asking, but I have the felling that only a tiny crucial bit is needed. Can you give more context of your use case and what ``MainClass.Account.create()`` is supposed to mean?

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: It sounds like you should be using composition rather than inheritance for `MainClass`. Why is it inheriting from two other classes which have conflicting implementations of a method? If it inherits from both, it should be calling the constructor for both.

Comment: @BryanOakley can show a little sample for MainClass using composition in this case.

Comment: Why don't you just name your methods `create_account()`, `create_user()`, ..?

Comment: I ended up moving MainClass from inheritance to composition as suggested by Bryan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, you have multiple inheritance, with:

```
class Base1(object):
    def create(self): ...

class Base2(object):
    def create(self): ...

class C(Base1, Base2):
    def create(self): ...
```

In class `C`, you can choose whether to call the implementation from the parent classes or not.

**Option 1:** do not implement `create` in class `C`

If you don't implement method `create` in `C`, then `Base1.create` is going to be used.

Note that this situation where `C` inherits from `Base1` and `Base2` is treated as if `C` inherites from `Base1` and `Base1` inherits from `Base2`.

You can see that if you `print C.__mro__`

See also this thread about MRO: [Method Resolution Order (MRO) in new style Python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-python-classes)

**Option 2:** do not call the base implemntation

```
class C(Base1, Base2):
    def create(self):
        pass
```

Now `Base1.create` is no longer going to be called.

**Option 3:** call only one of the bases

```
class C(Base1, Base2):
    def create(self):
        Base2.create(self)
```

Now `Base1.create` is not going to be called, but `Base2.create` is.

**Option 4:** call each of the base implementations

```
class C(Base1, Base2):
    def create(self):
        Base1.create(self)
        Base2.create(self)
```

Both `Base1.create` and `Base2.create` will be called.

**Option 5:** user `super` to call all base implementations

Although option 4 may seem like a very nice solution here, in some configurations, like diamond inheritance it could cause a method to be called multiple times. So, an alternative approach is to user `super`, which uses the MRO (see Option 1) to determine which base implementation to use. By using MRO, it avoids diamond inheritance problems. However, it has to be used systematically on all classes and even then it has its caveats.

```
class CommonBase(object):
    def create(self):
        pass

class Base1(CommonBase):
    def create(self):
        super(Base1, self).create()

class Base2(CommonBase):
    def create(self):
        super(Base2, self).create()

class C(Base1, Base2):
    def create(self):
        super(C, self).create()
```

Here, `C().create()` will call all four `create` methods, each once.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control it as a client of the class from the outside of the class, it can only be controlled inside a class, in your case inside `MainClass` by calling `super` to call a method from one or another base class: `Account` or  `User`.

```
class MainClass(Account, User):
  # your own convention that by default it calls Account.create
  def create(self, **params):
     super(Account, self).create(**params)

  def create2(self, **params):
     super(User, self).create(**params)
```