# how to understand this example of __getattr__ as metaclass method

Tags: python

Here is a snippet of example from Mark Lutz's book "Learning Python". I found it difficult to understand as to how name accesses are translated into getattr() calls in the metaclass:

```
>>> class A(type):
        def __getattr__(cls, name): 
            return getattr(cls.data, name) 

>>> class B(metaclass=A):                   
        data = 'spam'
>>> B.upper()
'SPAM'
>>> B.upper
<built-in method upper of str object at 0x029E7420>
>>> B.__getattr__
<bound method A.__getattr__ of <class '__main__.B'>>

>>> B.data = [1, 2, 3]
>>> B.append(4)
>>> B.data
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> B.__getitem__(0)
1
>>> B[0]
TypeError: 'A' object does not support indexing
```

I have the following questions:

1. how does B.upper() yield 'SPAM'? Is it because B.upper() => `A.__getattr__(B, upper())` => getattr(B.data, upper())? but a call like getattr('spam', upper()) gives error "NameError: name 'upper' is not defined"
2. what path does B.upper go to yiled `<built-in method upper of str object at 0x029E7420>`. does it go through getattr too, what is the true value of the arguments?
3. Does B.append(4) go through `A.__getattr__(cls, name)`? if it does, what is the true values of the arguments in getattr(cls.data, name) in this case?
4. how does `B.__getitem__(0)` yield 1? what is the true values of the arguments in getattr(cls.data, name) in this case?

Comment: using `B[0]` does not look up `B.__getitem__` but rather `type(B).__getitem__(B, 0)`, everything else is explained by the [method resolution order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-python-classes)

Comment: `B.upper()` => `A.__getattr__(B, "upper")()`

Comment: Would you mind elaborating the MRO in the context of this example?My difficulty is more on the format, or the true value of the argument, of getattr() calls in the metaclass which various name accesses are translated to.

Comment: Thank you spectras. That answered my question 1 and 3. would you care to explain question 2 and 4?

Comment: I think that answered my question 1, 3 and 4. would you care to explain question 2?

Comment: I think I got it. it's getattr('spam', "upper"). Thanks a lot,  spectras

Answer (score 3):

1. `B.upper()` first looks up `B.upper` and then calls it with no arguments. `B.upper` is looked up by trying several options in a certain order, eventually trying `type(B).__getattr__(B, 'upper')`, which in this case is `A.__getattr__(B, 'upper')`, which returns `'spam'.upper`.
2. As mentioned above, `B.upper` goes through several options, in this case reaching `type(B).__getattr__(B, 'upper')` which is `A.__getattr__(B, 'upper')`.
3. Yes, in this case, `B.append` will reach `A.__getattr__(B, 'append')` which will return `B.data.append`.
4. `B.__getitem__(0)` will in this case look up `B.__getitem__` and find it via `A.__getattr__(B, '__getitem__')` which will return `B.data.__getitem__`.

Also, note the final example, `B[0]`, doesn't work because the `B` class doesn't *directly* define a `__getitem__` method. This is because "special" methods, such as `__getitem__`, are looked up differently when used via their special syntax, such as `B[0]` in this case.

Comment: My question 2 is:
how does B.upper yiled <built-in method upper of str object at 0x029E7420>? does it go through A.__getattr__ and then getattr too? if so what is the true value of getattr's arguments?

Comment: This. Actually, questions #1 and #2 are the same. #2 yields the method, and #1, by adding the parenthesizes, calls it. Parenthesizes are not a special syntax in python, they just mean *“take what's on the left and try to invoke it as a function, passing those arguments”*.

Comment: @AlexL, if you find that this answer does answer your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

First you don't need to add the usual confusion of a meta class to get this behaviour, you can just as easily use a regular class and an instance to use as an example:

```
class A():
    def __getattr__(cls, name): 
        return getattr(cls.data, name) 

B = A()
B.data = "spam"

>>> B.data
'spam'
>>> B.upper
<built-in method upper of str object at 0x1057da730>
>>> B.upper()
'SPAM'
>>> B.__getitem__
<method-wrapper '__getitem__' of str object at 0x1057da730>
>>> B.__getitem__(0)
's'
>>> B[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#135>", line 1, in <module>
    B[0]
TypeError: 'A' object does not support indexing
```

Next keep in mind that `B[0]` does not look up `B.__getitem__` using your special method but rather tries to access it directly on `type(B)` which does not have a `__getitem__` so the indexing fails.

1. how does B.upper() yield 'SPAM'? Is it because B.upper() =>
   A.**getattr**(B, upper()) => getattr(B.data, upper())? but a call
   like getattr('spam', upper()) gives error "NameError: name 'upper'
   is not defined"

`getattr('spam', upper())` does not make any sense, the name of the attribute is always a string, so using `B.upper` (no calling yet) would be equivelent to `getattr(B, "upper")` then you call the method.

2. what path does B.upper go to yiled . does it go through getattr too, what is the
   true value of the arguments?

Is there any reason you are not just adding a print statement to check?

```
class A():
    def __getattr__(cls, name):
        print("calling __getattr__ for this name: %r"%name)
        return getattr(cls.data, name) 
>>> B = A()
>>> B.data = "spam"
>>> B.upper
calling __getattr__ for this name: 'upper'
<built-in method upper of str object at 0x1058037a0>
```

both 3 and 4 are answered by adding this print statement:

```
>>> B.data = [1,2,3,4]
>>> B.append(5)
calling __getattr__ for this name: 'append'
>>> B.__getitem__(0)
calling __getattr__ for this name: '__getitem__'
1
```