# Python3 , OOP : Multiple classes inheritance into single class

Tags: python, oop

I am Inheriting from multiple parent classes into a single class. What I am trying to do is make a situation of object data conflict.

I mean if two classes hold a variable with same name and different data, which data will be loaded by Python if that variable comes to picture?

what I did

```
>>> class pac:
...  var=10
...  var2=20
... 
>>> class cac:
...  var3=30
...  var2=10
... 

>>> pob=pac()
>>> cob=cac()
>>> pob.var
10
>>> pob.var2
20
>>> cob.var2
10
>>> cob.var3
30
>>> class newclass(pac,cac):
...  def sum(self):
...   sum=self.var+self.var2
...   sum2=self.var2+self.var3
...   print(sum)
...   print(sum2)
... 
30
50
>>> nob.var
10
>>> nob.var2
20
>>> nob.var3
30
>>>
```

It seems like `var2` data will consider from parent class : `pac` instead of `cac` class.

What needs to be done to make Python consider data from `cac` instead of `pac` if same variable name existed with different data? Please do not suggest me to change order of inheritance.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method Resolution Order (MRO) in new style Python classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-python-classes)

Comment: The data will be loaded in the order of inheritance, so changing that is the easiest way. Since you don't want to do that, could you clarify your question? Are you asking how to access the `var2` in `cac` from `newclass`?

Comment: Possibly interesting links: https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing the order of inheritance, your subclass will always get an attribute it can find in the first class, from the first class. If you want to find out what the corresponding value is in the second class, you're going to have to explicitly ask for the second class's value.

In your case, something like

```
class newclass(pac,cac):
    @property
    def var2(self):
        return cac.var2
```

Note that I'm explicitly asking for `cac`'s var2.

Answer (score 2):

You can set self.var2=cac.var2 in the newclass's **init** method:

```
class newclass(pac, cac):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var2 = cac.var2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also return a list/tuple of the possible values by using the following code:

```
@property
    def var2(self):
        key='var2'
        return [getattr(c,key) for c in self.__class__.mro()[1:-1] if hasattr(c,key)]
```

The `mro` method returns a list of classes, the first one will be the callers class followed by parents and lastly the `object` built-in class.
This code will return a list of values in the order of inheritance.