# How to handle multiple inheritance in python when parent init functions accept different numbers of arguments

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I have a class that inherits from 2 other classes, one of which has accepts an init argument. How do I properly initialize the parent classes?

So far I have:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.arg1 = arg1

class B(object):
    def  __init__(self):
         pass

class C(A, B):
     def __init__(arg1):
          super(C, self).__init__(arg1)
```

But this throws a `TypeError` as `B` doesn't receive an argument.

In context, `B` is the proper parent of `C`, whilst `A` is a mixin that many classes in the project inherit functionality from.

Comment: For multiple inheritance to be practical, at least one of the parents has to actually be designed for it. It doesn't look like either A or B is designed for it.

Comment: you should read about MRO in python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-python-classes

Comment: @giaosudau I did, actually; conceptually I get it but syntactically I don't understand how to implement what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually your question is about init parent class mean Class A or B right?
If so just create like normal A("hello") with B().

Comment: @giaosudau It's a nice idea but B is totally unrelated to A; these are mixins designed to pass a suite of functionality to classes that inherit from them.

Comment: The standard reference for this sort of thing is (Python core developer) Raymond Hettinger's "[Python's `super()` Considered Super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)", especially the "Practical Advice" and "Complete Example – Just for Fun" sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `__init__` of the parent classes manually.

```
class C(A, B):
     def __init__(arg1):
          A.__init__(self,arg1)
          B.__init__(self)
```