# Python diamond inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, diamond-problem

I'm trying to understand the behavior of following Python code.

```
class A(object):
    def print_x(self):
        print "In A: X"

class B(A):
    def print_x(self):
        super(B, self).print_x()
        print "In B: X"

class C(A):
    def print_x(self):
        super(C, self).print_x();
        print "In C: x"

class D(B, C):   # <----------- #1 
    def print_x(self):
        super(D, self).print_x()
        print "In D: x"

d = D();
d.print_x();
```

If I run above program I get an output like below:

```
In A: X
In C: x
In B: X
In D: x
```

If I change the statement `#1` in the code to `class D(C, B)` I get following output

```
In A: X
In B: X
In C: x
In D: x
```

Can anybody explain the internal working behind this code.

Comment: Why is that surprising?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-python-classes

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think surprise is not the question. Question is how and why?