# Python - Why attributes are not inherited?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

In the below code,

```
>>> class Employee:

    numOfEmployees = 0 
    raiseAmount = 1.04 

    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, pay):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = firstName + '.' + lastName + '@arista.com'

        Employee.numOfEmployees += 1

    def fullName(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.firstName, self.lastName)

    def appyRaise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raiseAmount)

        @classmethod
        def setRaiseAmt(cls, amount):
            cls.raiseAmount = amount

        @classmethod
        def createEmployee(cls, employeeStr):
            firstName, lastName, pay = employeeStr.split('-')
            return cls(firstName, lastName, pay)

        @staticmethod
        def isWorkDay(day):
            if day.weekday() == 5 or day.weekday() == 6:
                return False
            return True

>>> class Developer(Employee):
           pass


>>> Developer.__dict__
{'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
>>> Employee.__dict__
{'__module__': '__main__', 'createEmployee': <classmethod object at 0x7f2727731398>, 'numOfEmployees': 0, 'setRaiseAmt': <classmethod object at 0x7f27277310f8>, 'isWorkDay': <staticmethod object at 0x7f27277313d0>, 'appyRaise': <function appyRaise at 0x7f2727721f50>, 'fullName': <function fullName at 0x7f2727721ed8>, '__doc__': None, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0x7f2727721e60>, 'raiseAmount': 1.04}
>>>
```

---

**Question:**

Why `Developer.__dict__` does not show members of `Employee`? What exactly are we doing with syntax `class Developer(Employee)`?

Comment: Attribute inheritance doesn't work by copying everything out of the parent class's dict into the child's.

Comment: The instance dictionary is the same once the classes are instantiated.

Answer (score 3):

`__dict__` is the attributes specifically defined on the subclass, not its parents. When an attribute is looked up on the subclass and not found, it will scan the MRO (method resolution order, the set of parent classes) until it finds one that *does* have the desired attribute. Copying everything from the parent to the child `__dict__` would be wasteful on memory, and risk values getting out of sync (if the parent is monkey patched after the child is defined, and the child already cached a copy of the parent's `__dict__` within its own, everything would break).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the `__dict__` of the class objects, not of the instances.  If you look at the `__dict__` of a `Developer` instance, you will see the inherited attributes.  Methods (and class attributes) are resolved using the `mro`, as discussed at [Method Resolution Order (MRO) in new style Python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-python-classes).