# How to make super() work in this non-ideal situation in python?

Tags: python, pyside, multiple-inheritance, super, python-sip

```
class ClsOne(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClsOne, self).__init__()
        print "Here's One"

class ClsTwo(ClsOne):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClsTwo, self).__init__()
        print "Here's Two"

class ClsThree(ClsTwo): # Refer to one blackbox object
    def __init__(self):
        # super(ClsThree, self).__init__()
        print "Here's Three"

class ClsThreee(ClsTwo): # Refer to your custom object
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClsThreee, self).__init__()
        print "Here's Threee"

class ClsFour(ClsThree, ClsThreee): # Multiple Inheritance
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClsFour, self).__init__()
        print "Here's Four"

entity = ClsFour()
```

In this case, you are trying to combine *ClsThree* (which comes from a single compiled library and is very hard to change) and your own *ClsThreee* object together. Because *ClsThree* forgets to call *super()* in its constructor, their kid cannot execute ClsThreee's constructor when it uses *super()*.

As a result, the output will just like this:

```
Here's Three
Here's Four
```

Obviously, I can manually call every bases of ClsFour rather than use super(), but it's a bit complicated when this problem scattered all over my codebase.

By the way, that blackbox stuff is PySide :)

**SUPPLEMENT:**

Thanks to @WillemVanOnsem and @RaymondHettinger, the previous ClsFour question is solved. But with some further investigations, I found the similar problem in PySide doesn't have same concept.

In ClsFour context, if you try to run:

```
print super(ClsFour, self).__init__
```

You'll get:

```
<bound method ClsFour.__init__ of <__main__.ClsFour object at 0x00000000031EC160>>
```

But in the following PySide context:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyObject, self).__init__()
        print "Here's MyObject"

class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget, MyObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = MyWidget()
print super(MyWidget, widget).__init__
```

The result is:

```
<method-wrapper '__init__' of MyWidget object at 0x0000000005191D88>
```

It doesn't print "Here's MyObject" and the init attribute of super() has a different type as well. Previously, I try to simplify this problem as the ClsFour. But now I think it isn't totally the same.

I guess the problem occurs in shiboken library but I'm not sure.

TIPS:

The problem also appear in PyQt context, but you can make MyObject inherit from QObject to solve. This solution is useless in PySide.

Comment: It uses the MRO...

Comment: Don't know what the answer is but I have to say, I'm loving your naming scheme.

Comment: Yes it would defenitely help if your would call your classes for what the are... e.g. call ClsThree ClassFromLibraryCannotBeChanged and so on...

Comment: Not just ClsThree. Cls**Two** isn't performing superclass initialization either.

Comment: @user2357112: I've corrected it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`super()` is a *proxy* object that uses the ***Method Resolution Order (MRO)*** to determine what method to call when you perform a call on `super()`.

If we inspect the `__mro__` of `ClassFour`, we get:

```
>>> ClsFour.__mro__
(<class '__main__.ClsFour'>, <class '__main__.ClsThree'>, <class '__main__.ClsThreee'>, <class '__main__.ClsTwo'>, <class '__main__.ClsOne'>, <type 'object'>)
```

Or made it shorter myself (not the Python output):

```
>>> ClsFour.__mro__
(ClsFour, ClsThree, ClsThreee, ClsTwo, ClsOne, object)
```

Now `super(T,self)` is a proxy object that uses the MRO from (but excluding) `T`. So that means that `super(ClsFour,self)` is a proxy object that works with:

```
(ClsThree, ClsThreee, ClsTwo, ClsOne, object)  # super(ClsFour,self)
```

What will happen if you query an attribute (a method is also an attribute) of a class is that Python will walk through the MRO and inspect whether the element has such attribute. So it will first inspect whether `ClsThree` has an `__init__` attribute, if not it will continue to look for it in `ClsThreee` and so on. From the moment it finds such attribute it will stop, and return it.

So `super(ClsFour,self).__init__` will **return the `ClsThree.__init__` method**. The MRO is also used to find methods, attributes, etc. that are not defined on the class level. So if you use `self.x` and `x` is not an attribute of the object nor of the `ClsFour` object, it will again walk through the MRO in search for `x`.

If you want to call the `__init__` of *all* the *direct* parents of `ClassFour` you can use:

```
class ClsFour(ClsThree, ClsThreee):
    def __init__(self):
        # call *all* *direct* parents __init__
        for par in ClsFour.__bases__:
            par.__init__(self)
```

Which is probably the most elegant, since if the bases change, it will still work. Note that you have to make sure that `__init__` exists for every parent. Since it is however defined at the `object` level, we can safely assume this. For other attributes however, we can not make that assumption.

**EDIT**: Mind that as a result `super()` does **not** necessary points to the parents, grandparents and/or ancestors of that class. But to parent classes of the *object*.

The `super(ClsThree,self)` in the `ClsThree` class, will - given it is an `ClsFour` object, work with the **same mro** (since it takes the `mro` from the `self`). So `super(ClsThree,self)` will inspect the following sequence of classes:

```
(ClsThreee, ClsTwo, ClsOne, object)
```

For instance, if we write (out of the scope of any class) `super(ClsTwo,entity).__init__()`, we get:

```
>>> super(ClsTwo,entity).__init__()
Here's One
>>> super(ClsThree,entity).__init__()
Here's Two
Here's Threee
>>> super(ClsThreee,entity).__init__()
Here's Two
>>> super(ClsFour,entity).__init__()
Here's Three
```

Comment: If super() will just return the first method in MRO. Why it can execute the second base class if the first one doesn't lose its super().

Comment: What do you mean? Of course `ClsThree` can call `super(..)` as well and so you can create a chain of super calls.

Comment: Ah, I mean that ClsThreee isn't the base of ClsThree. But it's still executed when ClsFour perform a call on super() if ClsThree doesn't lose its super().

Comment: @Calven: mind that the super of `ClsThree` has the *same mro*, and thus only starts later. So the `super(ClsThree)` works with `(ClsThreee,ClsTwo,ClsOne,object)`.

Comment: Calling the `__init__` methods of all direct superclasses directly will lead to the same `__init__` methods getting called repeatedly in common cases; it only doesn't here because ClsThree (and ClsTwo) forget superclass initialization entirely instead of just not using `super`. Also, you probably want `ClsFour.__bases__` instead of `self.__class__.__bases__`, for pretty much the same reasons `super(self.__class__, self)` is wrong, and you're missing the `self` argument in `par.__init__`.

Comment: @user2357112: well `super(self.__class__,self)` evidently will - regardless of the class where it is called - lead to the same method - and thus can cause an infinite loop :). I do not advocate calling all the parents directly as a good remedy. It was meant to show that the two are different :).

Comment: If someone makes a subclass of `ClsFour` with your code, the loop over `self.__class__.__bases__` will call `ClsFour.__init__` over and over in an infinite loop.

Comment: @user2357112: I have found this issue of using loop on bases. That's definitely not the right way for solving this question.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Brilliant supplement. It makes scene now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: But with further investigation, I found this PySide problem is not as easy as I imagined, so I post something new on my question.

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

> Because ClsThree forgets to call super() in its constructor, their kid cannot execute ClsThreee's constructor when it uses super().

This is covered in the "How to Incorporate a Non-cooperative Class" section of [Super Considered Super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) blog post.

The key is to create an [adapter class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) that plays by the rules to act cooperatively by calling *super()*.  Use that adapter to wrap the original class.

### Worked-out code

In the code below, `AdaptThree` is the new adapter class and *ClsFour*
 now inherits from *AdaptThree* instead of the original blackbox non-cooperative class.

```
class ClsOne(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Here's One"

class ClsTwo(ClsOne):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Here's Two"

class ClsThree(ClsTwo): # Refer to one blackbox object
    def __init__(self):
        # super(ClsThree, self).__init__()
        print "Here's Three"

class AdaptThree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        _three = ClsThree()
        super(AdaptThree, self).__init__()          

class ClsThreee(ClsTwo): # Refer to your custom object
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClsThreee, self).__init__()
        print "Here's Threee"

class ClsFour(AdaptThree, ClsThreee): # Multiple Inheritance
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClsFour, self).__init__()
        print "Here's Four"

entity = ClsFour()
```

This outputs:

```
Here's Three
Here's Two
Here's Threee
Here's Four
```

### Other details

- In OP's example, *ClsTwo* also looks to be non-cooperative and should wrapped as well.
- Presumably these classes with have methods other than initialization.  The adapter classes will need to wrap and dispatch those calls as well.
- Depending on the application, it may be easier to use composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've read this popular blog before. I didn't choose this way due to your second detail. There're lots of other methods need to adapt as well and that's quite a heavy work. By the way, I've updated my question, I will appreciate your ideas for my supplement.

Comment: @Calven Have you tried writing a \__getattribute__ to auto-dispatch the remaining methods.

Comment: Do you mean something like self.__dict__.update(adapter.__dict__)?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue specific to PySide/PyQt4: one solution is to ensure that any mixins always preceed the Qt classes in the base-class definition:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, other=None):
        super(MyObject, self).__init__(parent)
        print "Here's MyObject: %r" % other

class MyWidget(MyObject, QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, other=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent, other)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
parent = QtGui.QWidget()
widget = MyWidget(parent, 'FOO')
print super(MyWidget, widget).__init__
# check that the QWidget.__init__ was called correctly
print 'widget.parent() is parent:', widget.parent() is parent
```

Output:

```
Here's MyObject: 'FOO'
<bound method MyWidget.__init__ of <__main__.MyWidget object at 0x7f53b92cca28>>
widget.parent() is parent: True
```

(NB: PyQt5 has improved [Support for Cooperative Multi-inheritance](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/multiinheritance.html#support-for-cooperative-multi-inheritance), so this issue doesn't arise there).

Comment: It works!!! I have tried this solution before but missed the parent parameter at that time. It causes the mixed object cannot be showed.