# how does str equality in Enum multiple inheritance work in python

Tags: python, enums, multiple-inheritance, equality

what is the mechanism by which the following `str` to `Enum` equality comparison works?

```
from enum import Enum

class SE(str, Enum):
    a = 'this'
    b = 'works'

assert SE.a == 'this', "i can't believe that worked"  # passes
```

whereas the following fails:

```
class E(Enum):
    a = 'this'
    b = 'does not'

assert E.a == 'this', "i'm not surprised that didn't"  # raises
```

the weird thing is that `str(SE.a) == 'SE.a'`, so i can't figure out how `SE.a == 'this'` works under the hood.

thanks.

to be clear: this is python 3.6

Comment: `assert E.a.value == this`

Answer (score 3):

In an `Enum`, there is no `__eq__` method; two instances are equal only if they are the same object, and the `EnumMeta` metaclass ensures that only one object per value is created.

```
class E(Enum):
    a = "foo"
    b = "foo"

assert E.a is E.b
```

`E.a == 'this'` is false because `E.a is 'this'` is false.

An instance of `SE`, though, is first and foremost a `str`, as can be seen in its method resolution order (MRO):

```
>>> SE.__mro__
(<enum 'SE'>, <class 'str'>, <enum 'Enum'>, <class 'object'>)
```

That means `SE.a == 'this'`, which is equivalent to `SE.__eq__(SE.a, 'this')` tries `str.__eq__(SE.a, 'this')` first, which evaluates to `True`.

Comment: first, thank you! this is so close to what i'm wondering, which until now i didn't even know i was wondering: how does `str.__str__(SE.a)` resolve to `'this'`  while `SE.__str__(SE.a)` resolves to `'SE.a'`...

Answer (score 2):

`SE` subclasses both `str` and `Enum` and `str` is higher on the [Method Resolution Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-classes).

```
class SE(str, Enum):
    a = 'this'
    b = 'works'

print(SE.mro())
# [<enum 'SE'>, <class 'str'>, <enum 'Enum'>, <class 'object'>]
```

This means that Python first searches a method in `str` and only then in `Enum`, which means that `str.__eq__` is used for the comparison.

Comment: the assertion won't even occur. mixins have to be first in inheritance order, at least in python 3.6+

Comment: @acushner you are correct, but `mro` is still the key here. See the updated answer

Comment: awesome! i see what's happening! thanks for putting me on the right track. the issue is that while `str(SE.a)` does equal `'SE.a'`, `str.__str__(SE.a)` equals `this`. and thus the equality makes sense. i still don't know why that's the case though...