# How do I call an indirect parent class's method from a child class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, parent, multiple-inheritance

I have classes A, B, and C. C inherits both from A and B, and for the most part wherever there are methods overriding each other I want A's to override B's, so I have the following structure:

```
class A:
    def some_method(self):
        return self.some_attribute

class B:
    def some_method(self):
        return self.some_other_attribute

class C(A,B):
    def some_method(self):
        var = super().some_method() -> this will give me the method from A, but I want the B one
        return var + 1
```

So my question is how can I invoke with super() or some other way the `some_method()` from B, so I can use it in the method override in C?

Also for the record I am using Python 3.*

Comment: This is a bad design and doesn't make sense. You should be extending a class to add or overwrite functionality NOT just throw a kitchen sink of essentially identical mixins together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is a language with multiple inheritance, which means that a class can have several direct superclasses. But for the purposes of calling `super()`, Python always *linearizes* the inheritance hierarchy to determine who the "best" superclass is. This is called the [method resolution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-classes), accessed via the `__mro__` variable in Python.

So if we have the class hierarchy

```
class A(object): pass
class B(A): pass
class C(A): pass
class D(B, C): pass
```

Then although `D` has two superclassses, if we say `super()` in `D`, it'll only give us `B`. That's because the MRO for `D` creates a linear hierarchy for us. In Python 3, it uses an algorithm called the [C3 resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization), which gives us this hierarchy

```
>>> D.__mro__
(<class 'D'>, <class 'B'>, <class 'C'>, <class 'A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

So if we call `super()` in a method on class `D`, we'll get the version on `B`, and if we call `super()` from there, we'll get the `C` version, then the `A` version, and finally the `object` one.

So in your case, `C` inherits from `A` and `B` (in that order), so it's going to be biased toward `A`. That is, the MRO for the class `C` in your example is `(C, A, B, object)`. If you want it to *always* go for `B` and then `A`, then simply switch the order of the superclasses.

```
class C(B, A):
  ...
```

This is the best solution. It's predictable and Python programmers will immediately understand the intention of a `super()` call in this class. I recommend this if it fits your needs.

However, if you have a complicated multi-inheritance system and need access to *both* the `A` and `B` superclasses at the same time, you can always call them directly with a class name, forgoing the `super()` call altogether.

```
class C(B, A):
  def some_method(self):
    A.some_method(self) # Calls A's version on self
    B.some_method(self) # Calls B's version on self
```

If `some_method` takes some arguments, you can pass them after the explicit `self` argument. This is going to raise more eyebrows, so if you find yourself needing access to two distinct superclass methods in complicated ways, you might consider refactoring your code to use less multiple inheritance. But the feature is there if you *really* need it.