# Implementing slicing in __getitem__

Tags: python, slice, python-datamodel

I am trying to implement slice functionality for a class I am making that creates a vector representation.

I have this code so far, which I believe will properly implement the slice but whenever I do something like `v[4]` where `v` is a vector, python raises an error about not having enough arguments. So I am trying to figure out how to define the `__getitem__` special method in my class to handle both plain indexes and slicing.

```
def __getitem__(self, start, stop, step):
    index = start
    if stop == None:
        end = start + 1
    else:
        end = stop
    if step == None:
        stride = 1
    else:
        stride = step
    return self.__data[index:end:stride]
```

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The `__getitem__()` method will receive a `slice` object when the object is sliced. Simply look at the `start`, `stop`, and `step` members of the `slice` object in order to get the components for the slice.

```
>>> class C(object):
...   def __getitem__(self, val):
...     print val
... 
>>> c = C()
>>> c[3]
3
>>> c[3:4]
slice(3, 4, None)
>>> c[3:4:-2]
slice(3, 4, -2)
>>> c[():1j:'a']
slice((), 1j, 'a')
```

Comment: Note: for extending builtins types like list or tuple you must implements `__getslice__` for python 2.X versions. see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__

Comment: @gregorySalvan: Doesn't that compatibility example below that section just recurse?

Comment: @Eric: No, because the presence of the second colon bypasses `__get/set/delslice__`. It's pretty subtle, though.

Comment: @user2357112: Wow, completely missed that second colon - thanks!

Comment: @alancalvitti IIRC, that's for creating new-style classes in Python 2.

Comment: Note that `__getitem__` *can* receive a `slice`, but could also receive an `int` as in `c[0]`. see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__

Answer (score 89):

I have a "synthetic" list (one where the data is larger than you would want to create in memory) and my `__getitem__` looks like this:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if isinstance(key, slice):
        # Get the start, stop, and step from the slice
        return [self[ii] for ii in xrange(*key.indices(len(self)))]
    elif isinstance(key, int):
        if key < 0: # Handle negative indices
            key += len(self)
        if key < 0 or key >= len(self):
            raise IndexError, "The index (%d) is out of range." % key
        return self.getData(key) # Get the data from elsewhere
    else:
        raise TypeError, "Invalid argument type."
```

The slice doesn't return the same type, which is a no-no, but it works for me.

Comment: Shouldn't if key >= len( self ) be if key < 0 or key >= len( self ) ? What if a key < -len(self) is passed?

Comment: Instead of `"Invalid argument type"` I suggest a more helpful`f"{type(self).__name__} indices must be integers or slices, not {type(key).__name__}"` (inspired by what you get if you try `a["hello"]` when `a` is a simple python list)

Answer (score 35):

> ## How to define the getitem class to handle both plain indexes and slicing?

Slice objects gets automatically created when you use a colon in the subscript notation - and *that* is what is passed to `__getitem__`. Use `isinstance` to check if you have a slice object:

```py
from __future__ import print_function

class Sliceable(object):
    def __getitem__(self, subscript):
        if isinstance(subscript, slice):
            # do your handling for a slice object:
            print(subscript.start, subscript.stop, subscript.step)
        else:
            # Do your handling for a plain index
            print(subscript)
```

Say we were using a range object, but we want slices to return lists instead of new range objects (as it does):

```py
>>> range(1,100, 4)[::-1]
range(97, -3, -4)
```

We can't subclass range because of internal limitations, but we can delegate to it:

```py
class Range:
    """like builtin range, but when sliced gives a list"""
    __slots__ = "_range"
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._range = range(*args) # takes no keyword arguments.
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._range, name)
    def __getitem__(self, subscript):
        result = self._range.__getitem__(subscript)
        if isinstance(subscript, slice):
            return list(result)
        else:
            return result

r = Range(100)
```

We don't have a perfectly replaceable Range object, but it's fairly close:

```py
>>> r[1:3]
[1, 2]
>>> r[1]
1
>>> 2 in r
True
>>> r.count(3)
1
```

To better understand the slice notation, here's example usage of Sliceable:

```
>>> sliceme = Sliceable()
>>> sliceme[1]
1
>>> sliceme[2]
2
>>> sliceme[:]
None None None
>>> sliceme[1:]
1 None None
>>> sliceme[1:2]
1 2 None
>>> sliceme[1:2:3]
1 2 3
>>> sliceme[:2:3]
None 2 3
>>> sliceme[::3]
None None 3
>>> sliceme[::]
None None None
>>> sliceme[:]
None None None
```

#### Python 2, be aware:

In Python 2, there's a deprecated method that you may need to override when subclassing some builtin types.

From the [datamodel documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__):

> `object.__getslice__(self, i, j)`
>
> **Deprecated since version 2.0:** Support slice objects as parameters to the `__getitem__()` method. (However, built-in types in CPython currently still implement `__getslice__()`. Therefore, you have to override it in derived classes when implementing slicing.)

This is gone in Python 3.

Comment: when we handle plain indices, we cannot call self[index] as it'll go into recursion, how do you access the right element?

Comment: If you want to use a parent's implementation of a method you are already in, use `super()`.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python-difference-between-super-init-and-expl/33469090#33469090

Answer (score 9):

To extend Aaron's answer, for things like `numpy`, you can do multi-dimensional slicing by checking to see if `given` is a `tuple`:

```
class Sliceable(object):
    def __getitem__(self, given):
        if isinstance(given, slice):
            # do your handling for a slice object:
            print("slice", given.start, given.stop, given.step)
        elif isinstance(given, tuple):
            print("multidim", given)
        else:
            # Do your handling for a plain index
            print("plain", given)

sliceme = Sliceable()
sliceme[1]
sliceme[::]
sliceme[1:, ::2]
```

```

Output:

```
('plain', 1)
('slice', None, None, None)
('multidim', (slice(1, None, None), slice(None, None, 2)))
```

Comment: As a minor follow-up, here [is an example](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/62151af/bindings/mlmodule/NumPyProxy.m#L83) of employing this to map between MATLAB indexing and NumPy indexing (which is presently not supported in MATLAB R2016b), with an [example usage](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/62151af/bindings/mlmodule/test/example_py_slice.m#L43) of it.

Answer (score 8):

The correct way to do this is to have [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) take one parameter, which can either be a number or a [slice](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#slice) object.