# How does work this pythonic trick: a[::-1]

Tags: python

```
>> a = range(10)
>> print a[::-1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

This slice gives reversed list. How does it work?

Comment: I'd argue it's more "pythonic" to use 
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0].reverse() . In Python the focus should usually be on readability.

Comment: Or even `reversed(aSeq)` if you want the efficiency of an iterator

Comment: @SpliFF - they do slightly different things though.

Comment: @SpliFF, `[::-1]` works for strings too though. I think it's a good idiom to know because `''.join(reversed(mystr))` isn't exactly readable either

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The third argument is a step modifier.  In this case you are using a step of `-1`.

You could also use a step of `2` to print every even index.

```
>>> a = range(10)
>>> a[::2]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> a[::-2]
[9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Once you *grok* extended slices, be sure to appreciate the under appreciated  [slice()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#slice) function:

```
>>> for sl in [(1,-1),(0,20,3),(10,),(None,None,-3),(None,None,4)]:
...    print range(20)[slice(*sl)]
... 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[19, 16, 13, 10, 7, 4, 1]
[0, 4, 8, 12, 16]
```

It is especially useful for [fixed length data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911483/python-slice-how-to-i-know-the-python-slice-but-how-can-i-use-built-in-slice-ob) formats.

Answer (score 2):

This is the extended slice syntax. [See the docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html).

For `range(x,y,z)` x is the start, y is the stop, z is the stride.

This has been covered well in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/455276).