# How can list[n] point to list[0]? Getting items not in sequence

Tags: python

I'm not sure about the term of this technique. I want to create a list where if I try to access an element outside the list range, the list would "loop itself". Example of the behaviour I want to achieve:

```
>>> musical_scale = ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B']
>>> musical_scale[2]
E
>>> musical_scale[7]
C
>>> musical_scale[-1]
B
```

I guess I could write a class which does this, but I thought there might be a more correct way of doing it.

Comment: Writing a class is as "correct" a method as any.

Comment: No, writing a class is the first thing I thought of. It'd be easy to overload one of the magic methods and mod the requested index by the length.

Comment: why not use mod? it's more efficient.

Comment: This is a Ring structure. You can also do it with Linked Lists. Bonus points if you can turn it into a Moebius Strip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the modulus operator `%` to "loop back" after indexing past the end of the list

```
>>> musical_scale = ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B']

def getValue(x, l):
    return l[x % len(l)]

>>> getValue(0, musical_scale)
'C'
>>> getValue(9, musical_scale)
'E'
```

Comment: Somewhat limited though. What about assignment, slicing etc?

Comment: I only attempted to answer the OP's use case. If more involved indexing (such as slicing) is a requirement, the function needs to do more work.

Answer (score 4):

Creating a subclass of List would be a pretty useful way of doing this. Something like this, perhaps:

```
class modList(list):

  def __getitem__(self, i):
    if len(self) == 0:
      raise IndexError   # Or do something else if you want, like return []
    i = i % len(self)   # self.__len__() works also
    return super(modList, self).__getitem__(i)   # In Python 3, super().__getitem__(i)
```

If you want to do slicing, it's a little more complicated, but similar. Found this while looking through StackOverflow:

```
  def __getitem__(self, i):
    if isinstance(i, int):
      if len(self) == 0:
        raise IndexError
      i = i % len(self)
      return super(modList, self).__getitem__(i)   # list.__getitem__(i) works too
    elif isinstance(i, slice):
      if len(self) == 0:
        return []
      start = i.start % len(self)
      stop = i.stop % len(self)
      step = i.step
      return super(modList, self).__getItem__(slice(start, stop, step))
    else:
      raise TypeError("invalid index")
```

Though this slice modding could give you a situation like `[3:2]`, which will return an empty list. Basically slicing is hard and you'll need to decide how you want to implement it, but hopefully this is a start.

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/3911483/python-slice-how-to-i-know-the-python-slice-but-how-can-i-use-built-in-slice-ob

(Thanks @JonClements for all the suggestions in chat.)

EDIT: now we have some handlers for if you have an empty list. @wim suggests raising an error for single accesses, and returning `[]` for slices. Really it's up to you what you want to do but that seemed sensible to me, so that's what I've included in this answer.

EDIT EDIT: if you're using Python 2.x, I believe you also need to override `__getslice__`.

Comment: Umm... Inherit from `list`, scrap your `__init__` and just over-ride `__getitem__`... you've only complicated this and reduced its usability by using containership and inheriting from `object`.

Comment: @JonClements good idea. I reworked the answer into something that's (hopefully) more useful.

Comment: +1 looks promising.  still needs work to handle the empty list case.

Comment: oops, but getting an item from empty list will now return empty list instead of raising IndexError  ;)

Comment: @wim I figured that the point of this class was to push IndexErrors away, so I thought returning something might be more useful. Really it's up to the OP what he wants to happen in that case.

Comment: hmm, I don't agree, I think getting a slice from empty list should return empty list, but accessing an index should return an element or raise (homogeneous return types)

Comment: @wim that seems pretty reasonable. I've made that the default and added something about handling it however the OP likes.

Comment: -1 for not following [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#code-lay-out) guidelines.

Comment: @martineau that's the level of indentation that is highly encouraged/enforced where I work, so it's what I default to. Plus my comments fit without scrolling the answer box at the moment, so I will acknowledge that I am violating PEP-8 without making the change.

Answer (score 0):

In case you'd like to extend the list class to handle getting and setting...

```
class UnsatList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        try:
            return list.__getitem__(self, index % len(self))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            raise IndexError('list assignment index out of range')

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        try:
            return list.__setitem__(self, index % len(self), value)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            raise IndexError('list assignment index out of range')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_list = UnsatList([1,2,3,4])
    assert test_list[0] == 1
    assert test_list[4] == 1
    assert test_list[8] == 1
    assert test_list[-8] == 1
    test_list[4] = 5
    assert test_list[0] == 5
    assert test_list[4] == 5
    assert test_list[8] == 5
    assert test_list[-8] == 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, but remember [The Zen of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): **Flat is better than nested.**

You can write for example:

```
a = [1, [2]]
a[1].append(a)
```

Then your list a has "infinite depth", and you can loop on these two elements by repeatedly doing:

```
a[0]
a = a[1]
```

You can't do that without playing with depth, because unlike e.g. Lisp, Python lists are varying-length arrays, not linked-lists.

Here are little functions to do the whole stuff automatically:

```
def loopify(a):
    r = b = []
    for x in a:
        b.append(x)
        b.append([])
        c = b
        b = b[1]
    c[1] = r
    return r

def loopgen(a):
    while True:
        yield a[0]
        a = a[1]
```

Then with your example:

```
musical_scale = loopify(['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B'])
g = loopgen(musical_scale)
[next(g) for i in range(20)]
```

This yields:

['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A']

Of course, it's also possible to use mod or to keep track of the current index and reseting it to 0 when you overflow your list. Other answers show you how to do that.

Also notice that the linked-list approach does not permit random access, only sequential access (thus the generator above). If you need to access you list randomly, modular arithmetic is the most appropriate way.