# How can I use colon (:) in variable

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, variables

I want to write code like this:

```
index = 0:2
print(list[index])
```

but this does not work.

Is there any way I can store all parts of the `[...:...]` syntax in a variable?

Comment: No you cannot. That is not valid Python Syntax.

Comment: No , in Python its not possible to do that for integers/floats. You can use them for string (Ex :  index = "0:2").

Comment: @leaf: there is valid syntax to express the *intent* however.

Comment: @Turry: but that string can not be used in a subscription.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Of course there is. You just beat me to the punch with your answer :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters , you are right , I answered the question :"How to put that in a variable". Also , really nice answer you have given here.

Comment: Related post and a nice read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911483/python-slice-how-to-i-know-the-python-slice-but-how-can-i-use-built-in-slice-ob

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You want a [`slice()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice):

```
index = slice(0, 2)
print(somelist[index])
```

`slice()` models the start, stop and stride values you can specify in the  `[start:stop:stride]` subscription syntax, as an object.

From the documentation:

> Return a [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice) object representing the set of indices specified by `range(start, stop, step)`. The start and step arguments default to `None`. Slice objects have read-only data attributes `start`, `stop` and `step` which merely return the argument values (or their default).

Under the covers, Python actually translates subscriptions to a `slice()` object when calling custom `__getitem__` methods:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __getitem__(self, item):
...         return item
...
>>> Foo()[42:81:7]
slice(42, 81, 7)
>>> Foo()[:42]
slice(None, 42, None)
```

A viable alternative would be to store start and stop as separate values:

```
startindex = 0
stopindex = 2
print(somelist[start:stop])
```

Comment: thanks, but what about "index = -2:"

Comment: @giorgishengelaia Your doing it wrong. Just store the `index` variable with a value of `-2`. Then say `print(somelist[index:])`.

Comment: @giorgishengelaia: that be `slice(-2, None)`. Try out my `Foo()` example; `Foo()[-2:]` returns `slice(-2, None, None)`.

Comment: @leaf: what if you wanted to model `-2:` at one time, and `:4` another?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not sure I see what your getting at?

Comment: @leaf: your approach, `index = -2` and `somelist[index:]` limits you to only making the starting point variable. You could use *three* variables, one for start, stop and stride, respectively, then use `somelist[start:stop:stride]` everywhere, but that's very verbose. Using a `slice()` object is far more elegant here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm sorry, I don't get your argument. In his second question, I didn't see any need for a `slice()` object because he only had a start value. Why should he use `slice()` instead of a slice variable with one value?

Comment: @MartijnPieters You got me right.

Comment: @leaf I want to use "index = -2:" and "index = 0:2" at the same time.

Comment: @leaf: Yes, in their example they only had a start variable. Yet in the question they had an *end variable* (ignoring the start defaulting to `0`). So this is clearly a question about modelling all portions of a slice, not just a single value in a slice.

Comment: @leaf: comments are not for extended discussion however. If you want to talk more about this, I'm in the [Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).

Comment: if I wanted to use only "index = -2:", I would not use variable("index")

Answer (score 11):

You can instead create a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) object:

```
index = slice(0,2)
print(lst[index])
```

Be careful not to use `list` as name to avoid shadowing the builtin `list` function.

From the docs:

> `slice(start, stop[, step])`
>
> Return a slice object representing the set of indices specified by
>   `range(start, stop, step)`