# Pandas how does IndexSlice work

Tags: python, pandas

I am following this tutorial: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/TomAugspurger/pydata-chi-h2t/blob/master/3-Indexing.ipynb)

If you scroll down (Ctrl+F: Exercise: Select the most-reviewd beers ) to the section that says `Exercise: Select the most-reviewd beers`:

The dataframe is multindexed:
[image]

To select the most-reviewed beers:

```
top_beers = df['beer_id'].value_counts().head(10).index
reviews.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, top_beers], ['beer_name', 'beer_style']]
```

My question is the way of how the IndexSlice is used, how come you can skip the colon after top_beers and the code still run?

```
reviews.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, top_beers, :], ['beer_name', 'beer_style']]
```

There are three indexes, `pofile_name`, `beed_id` and `time`. Why does `pd.IndexSlice[:, top_beers]` work (without specify what to do with the time column)?

Comment: That's what the `:` operator does. You are filtering by only one of the three columns of the hierarchical index. The other two (the ones using `:`) can take any value. You can think of `:` as a filter that matches `True` for any value.

Comment: @GustavoBezerra the problem is that even without the third `:` the code still works. `reviews.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, top_beers], ['beer_name', 'beer_style']]` works even without the third `:'

Comment: top_beers is a list.  your filtering the second level index field beer id by the top_beers.  The other two levels are defaulting all values.  if you want to slice by range use slice(a:b)

Answer (score 18):

This answer explains how [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html) works and why it is useful.

There is not much to say about its implementation. As you read in the [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/indexing.py), it just does the following:

```
class IndexSlice(object):
    def __getitem__(self, arg):
        return arg
```

From this one can see that `pd.IndexSlice` only passes the arguments that `__getitem__` has received. Looks pretty pointless, doesn't it? But it actually does something.

The function [`obj.__getitem__(arg)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) is called when anobject `obj` is accessed through its bracket operator `obj[arg]`. For sequence-like objects, `arg` can be either an integer or a [slice object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice). We rarely construct slices ourselves. Rather, we use the slice operator `:` (aka ellipsis) for this purpose, e.g. `obj[0:5]`.

And here is the crucial point: The Python interpretor converts these slice operators `:` into slice objects before calling the object's `__getitem__(arg)` method. Therefore, the return value of `IndexSlice.__getItem__()`  will actually be a slice, an integer (if no `:` was used), or a tuple of these (if multiple arguments are passed). In summary, the only purpose of `IndexSlice` is that we do not have to construct the slices ourselves. This behavior is particularly useful for `pd.DataFrame.loc`.

The following examples illustrate the behavior of `pd.IndexSlice`:

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.IndexSlice
print(idx[0])               # 0
print(idx[0,'a'])           # (0, 'a')
print(idx[:])               # slice(None, None, None)
print(idx[0:3])             # slice(0, 3, None)
print(idx[0.1:2.3])         # slice(0.1, 2.3, None)
print(idx[0:3,'a':'c'])     # (slice(0, 3, None), slice('a', 'c', None))
```

We observe that all usages of colons `:` are converted into slice objects. If multiple arguments are passed to the index operator, the arguments are turned into n-tuples.

The next example demonstrates how this could be useful for a pandas data-frame `df` with a multi-level index:

```
# A sample table with three-level row-index
# and single-level column index.
import numpy as np
level0 = range(0,10)
level1 = list('abcdef')
level2 = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV']
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([level0, level1, level2])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([len(mi),2]), 
                  index=mi, columns=['col1', 'col2'])

# Return a view on 'col1', selecting all rows.
df.loc[:,'col1']            # pd.Series         

# Note in the above example that the returned value has
# type pd.Series, since only one column is returned. One 
# can force the returned object to be a data frame:
df.loc[:,['col1']]          # pd.DataFrame, or
df.loc[:,'col1'].to_frame() # 

# Select all rows with top-level values 0:3.
df.loc[0:3, 'col1']   

# To create a slice for multiple index levels, we need to
# somehow pass a list of slices. The following, however,
# leads to a SyntaxError because the slice operator ':'
# cannot be placed inside a list declaration directly.
df.loc[[0:3, 'a':'c'], 'col1'] 

# The following is valid python code, but looks clumsy:
df.loc[(slice(0, 3, None), slice('a', 'c', None)), 'col1']

# This is why pd.IndexSlice is useful. It helps to
# create slices that use two index-levels.
df.loc[idx[0:3, 'a':'c'], 'col1'] 

# We can expand the slice specification by a third level.
df.loc[idx[0:3, 'a':'c', 'I':'III'], 'col1'] 

# A solitary slicing operator ':' means: take them all.
# It is equivalent to slice(None).
df.loc[idx[0:3, 'a':'c', :], 'col1'] # pd.Series

# Semantically, this is equivalent to the following,
# because the last ':' in the previous example does 
# not add any information to the slice specification.
df.loc[idx[0:3, 'a':'c'], 'col1']    # pd.Series

# The following lines are also equivalent, but
# both expressions evaluate to a result with multiple columns.
df.loc[idx[0:3, 'a':'c', :], :]    # pd.DataFrame
df.loc[idx[0:3, 'a':'c'], :]       # pd.DataFrame
```

In summary, `pd.IndexSlice` improves readability when specifying complicated slices.

What pandas does with these slices is another story. It selects rows/columns, starting from the topmost index level and reduces the selection as it goes further down, depending on how many levels are specified. `pd.DataFrame.loc` is an object with its own `__getitem__()` function that does all this.

As has been pointed out in a comment, pandas seemingly behaves weird in some special cases. The two examples the OP has mentioned will evaluate to the same result. However, they are treated differently by pandas internally.

```
# This will work.
reviews.loc[idx[top_reviewers,        99, :], ['beer_name', 'brewer_id']]
# This will fail with TypeError "unhashable type: 'Index'".
reviews.loc[idx[top_reviewers,        99]   , ['beer_name', 'brewer_id']]
# This fixes the problem. (pd.Index is not hashable, a tuple is.
# However, the problem affects only the second expression, since
# pandas can get around hashable indices in one case, but it
# cannot in the other.)
reviews.loc[idx[tuple(top_reviewers), 99]   , ['beer_name', 'brewer_id']]
```

Admittedly, the difference is subtle.

Comment: What indices were float numbers? how would it work then?

Comment: @arash: The same. `slice()` is agnostic of datatypes. It just bundles information about `start`, `end` and `step`. How a particular slice (e.g. `slice(0.1, 2.3, 4.5)`) is interpreted, depends on the object receiving the slice. For a `df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=[0.1,2.3,4.5])` you can access all columns by `idx[0.1:4.5]`, which is consistent with the behavior for other index types. And it's not too surprising that `pandas` raises an error for `idx[0.1:4.5:2.3]` because it cannot give sense to a float-type step.

Comment: @arash See maybe also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3912107/3388962)

Answer (score 5):

Pandas only requires you to specify enough levels of the MultiIndex to remove an ambiguity. Since you're slicing on the 2nd level, you need the first `:` to say I'm not filtering on this level.

Any additional levels not specified are returned in their entirety, so equivalent to a `:` on each of those levels.

Comment: If that is the case then why can't I remove the colon from this line within the same tutorial `reviews.loc[pd.IndexSlice[top_reviewers, 99,:], ['beer_name', 'brewer_id']]`, if I remove the colon and comma after `99`, I get a `unhashable type: 'Index'` error

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head. Based on the error message, about `Index` being unhashable, it's possible it's taking a different indexing path. You could open an issue on github with a simpler example and we'll take a look.

Comment: @Cheng: The problem is that `top_reviewers` is of type `pd.Index`, which apparently is not hashable out of the box. To fix this, you could transform it into a list first (which can be further transformed into a hashable object). So the following will work: `reviews.loc[pd.IndexSlice[top_reviewers.tolist(), 99], ['beer_name', 'brewer_id']]`

Comment: @Cheng But it's true that you discovered a small inconsistency in the way pandas processes slices: `top_reviewers` in `pd.IndexSlice[top_reviewers, 99, :]` and `pd.IndexSlice[top_reviewers, 99]` is not treated in exactly the same way, the latter leading to an error, while the former does not.