# How to invert a list of strings left to right

Tags: python, function

I have a bunch of lists and I want to inverse their string content from left to right.
How to transform `x`

```
x = ['TARDBP', 'BUB3', 'TOP2A', 'SYNCRIP', 'KPNB1']
```

to

```
x = ['KPNB1', 'SYNCRIP', 'TOP2A', 'BUB3', 'TARDBP']
```

Comment: x.reverse().  Better yet `help(x)` and read it!

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: x = x[::-1] [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3911763/7070779) explains it very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def reverse(L):
  if L == []:
    return []
  else:
    return reverse(L[1:]) + [L[0]]


print(['TARDBP', 'BUB3', 'TOP2A', 'SYNCRIP', 'KPNB1'])
print(reverse(['TARDBP', 'BUB3', 'TOP2A', 'SYNCRIP', 'KPNB1']))
```

Answer (score 2):

As simple as

```
x = x[::-1]
```

.......

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
x = x[::-1]
```

or this:

```
x = list(reversed(x))
```

You can also perform an in-place reverse as follows:

```
x.reverse()
```

Comment: is `list` optional?

Comment: @Don because reversed(x) returns a iterator, and the OP wants a list.. do you have anther suggestion ?

Comment: You're right. I thought `reversed` returned a list