# How can I provide syntactic sugar for slicing a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-indexing

I would like to write more readable code by doing something like:

```
import numpy as np

SLICE_XY = slice(0, 2)
SLICE_Z = slice(2, 3)

data = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
                 [3, 4, 5],
                 [6, 7, 8],
                 [9, 10, 11]])

xy = data[:, SLICE_XY]
z = data[:, SLICE_Z]
```

However, I have run into the issue that doing the above produces

```
>>> xy
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 9, 10]])
>>> z
array([[ 2],
       [ 5],
       [ 8],
       [11]])
```

which is what I expected for `xy`. But for `z` I expected it to be equivalent to

```
>>> data[:, 2]
array([ 2,  5,  8, 11])
```

Note:

```
>>> data[:, 0:2]
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 9, 10]])
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3912120/567595) is helpful for converting slice notation into a tuple that can be stored. e.g. you could say `SLICE_Z = slice(None, None, None), 2` then `z = data[SLICE_Z]`

Comment: `np.s_` and `np.r_` may also be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SLICE_Z = 2
```

By design, arr[0:1] is not the same as arr[0]. Slices always return iterables.