# Subset a string based on variable

Tags: python, string, indexing

Suppose we have a long string, for example:

`s = "The long-string instrument is a musical instrument in which the string is of such a length that the fundamental transverse wave is below what a person can hear as a tone."`

Now, We all know how to extract from this string letters based on indexes:

```
z = s[18:26]
print(z)
strument
```

But is there any way, how I can assign this indexes to a variable, and then subset the list based on this variable? It should look something like that:

```
z = [18:26]
print(s.z)
strument
```

Comment: I added an answer I wanted to put here in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911483/python-slice-how-to-i-know-the-python-slice-but-how-can-i-use-built-in-slice-ob/57546434#57546434 about using numpy's `s_`, which I think may better answer your question. I was unable to post it as this question was so rapidly closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you look for are the [slice objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice):

```
z = slice(18,26)
print(s[z])
```