# ValueError: Shape mismatch: if categories is an array, it has to be of shape (n_features,)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, spyder, one-hot-encoding

I have create a simple code to implement `OneHotEncoder`.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
X = [[0, 'a'], [0, 'b'], [1, 'a'], [2, 'b']]
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categories=[0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

I just want to use method called `fit_transform` to the `X` for index `0`, so it means for `[0, 0, 1, 2]` like what you see in `X`. But it causes an error like this :

`ValueError: Shape mismatch: if categories is an array, it has to be of shape (n_features,).`

Anyone can solve this problem ? I am stuck on it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use  `ColumnTransformer` to specify the column index not `categories` parameter.

Constructor parameter `categories` is to tell distinct category values explicitly. E.g. you could provide `[0, 1, 2]` explicitly, but `auto` will determine it. Further, you can use [`slice()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911483/python-slice-how-to-i-know-the-python-slice-but-how-can-i-use-built-in-slice-ob) object instead.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

X = [[0, 'a'], [0, 'b'], [1, 'a'], [2, 'b']]

ct = ColumnTransformer(
    [('one_hot_encoder', OneHotEncoder(categories='auto'), [0])],   # The column numbers to be transformed (here is [0] but can be [0, 1, 3])
    remainder='passthrough'                                         # Leave the rest of the columns untouched
)

X = ct.fit_transform(X)
```

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.get_dummies()` method also can do same in the way below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
X = np.array([[0, 'a'], [0, 'b'], [1, 'a'], [2, 'b']])
X = np.array(pd.concat([pd.get_dummies(X[:, 0]), pd.DataFrame(X[:, 1])], axis = 1))
```