# Shape mismatch issue with OneHotEndcoder

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

This is my code

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
X[:,0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:,0])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categories=[])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

After trying many times i am not able to solve this error

```
ValueError: Shape mismatch: if categories is an array, it has to be of shape (n_features,).
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Shape mismatch: if categories is an array, it has to be of shape (n\_features,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525929/valueerror-shape-mismatch-if-categories-is-an-array-it-has-to-be-of-shape-n)

Answer (score 2):

From your code, it's not entirely clear what are you trying to do, but the error is due to this line:

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categories=[])
```

The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) says `categories` argument specifies the order of the one-hot encoded columns returned. If you have `n` categories in the column you're trying to encode, the length of the `categories` list should be `n`. But you're passing an empty list. If you do not specify that, the value `categories` will default to `auto` which will automatically determine the categories from data.

In order to *fix your error*, do this:

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder()
```