# How to check if second value of slice() is a certain value?

Tags: python, list, function, slice

I have a function that takes in a slice. What I want to do is to check if the end value in this slice is equal to -1. If that is the case, I want to reset the slice to another value. I can't find supporting documentation and do not know how to proceed.

```
datalist=[None, 'Grey', 'EE20-700', 'EE-42-01', 'EE15-767', 'EE0-70650', 'B&B', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, '300R', True, 'Nov. 2, 2022', 'Nov. 2, 2022', 1, 1, 1, True, 3]

#If we just apply the given slice_dimensions, the following happens:
slice_dimensions=slice(1, -1)
datalist[slice_dimensions]
['Grey', 'EE20-700', 'EE-42-01', 'EE15-767', 'EE0-70650', 'B&B', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, '300R', True, 'Nov. 2, 2022', 'Nov. 2, 2022', 1, 1, 1, True]
```

As you can see this is problematic, because the last element of my list (3) is omitted with the current slice dimension. I have seen many solutions saying I should use len(datalist)-1 or something similar instead, but this is not a workable option because the list lengths differ, and I want to keep it simple. If we can just check if end of slice is equal to -1 and change it to None, the problem is solved:

```
#If we just apply the given slice_dimensions, the following happens:
slice_dimensions=slice(1, None)
datalist[slice_dimensions]
['Grey', 'EE20-700', 'EE-42-01', 'EE15-767', 'EE0-70650', 'B&B', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, '300R', True, 'Nov. 2, 2022', 'Nov. 2, 2022', 1, 1, 1, True, 3]
```

I would like to make a function to do so, but do not know how to proceed, something like this:

```
def slicer(slice_dimensions):
    if slice_dimensions[1] == -1:  #This part I do not know how to proceed
        slice_dimensions= slice(1, None)
    data_of_interest=datalist[slice_dimensions]
    return(data_of_interest)
```

How should I proceed in doing so?

Comment: Having mixed types in a list is a big red flag - that kind of thing is absolutely more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it's a built-in type name.

Comment: `len(l)-1` can be called on each `list` to always get the correct length - how is that not simple?

Comment: @Edward Peters, because the list is generated from ```[cell.value for cell in worksheet[i]]```

Comment: The values of a `slice` object are available as the `start`, `stop`, and `step` attributes.

Comment: `slicer` looks fine, though you can use `slice_dimensions.stop` as a more self-explanatory version of `slice_dimensions[1]`. It's not clear, though, why you need to second-guess the caller. If they wanted the results of `slice(1, None)`, they could pass that instead of `slice(1, -1)` in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar, it is an example list, in truth its not called list!

Comment: Don't use it in examples, either.

Comment: What is `<-` supposed to be? Why isn't that just an ordinary `=` assignment?

Comment: Why doesn't `slicer()` take the list as a parameter? It shouldn't be hard-coded to a specific list variable.

Comment: Why is it a problem that the last element is omitted? Isn't that what they wanted when they said `slice_dimensions = slice(1, -1)`? Is the stop value being calculated in a way that might go below zero without wanting it to wrap around? That seems like the place to address this.

Comment: I changed ```list``` to ```datalist```... Also, the solution from @chepner with ```slice_dimensions.stop``` seems to be very helpful. @Barmar, I quickly worked this out, have been using too much R, and confused ```<-``` with ```=```, in addition, slicer does take datalist in the actual example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python slice how-to, I know the Python slice but how can I use built-in slice object for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911483/python-slice-how-to-i-know-the-python-slice-but-how-can-i-use-built-in-slice-ob)

Comment: @Barmar, in actuality the datalist comes from a row in an excel form. These are added to Django databases, the row size in the excel can sometimes be longer than the number of columns allowed, and need to be sliced. If the -1 is used as default this is not the case, but then I want to change it to None otherwise the last list item element is omitted. Perhaps I should use len(datalist)-1.

Comment: This just sounds like a bug in whatever thought `-1` was a usable sentinel value. `foo[x:]` equivalent to `foo.__getitem__(slice(x, None))`, not `foo.__getitem__(slice(x, -1))`.

Comment: `len(datalist)-1` is equivalent to `-1` in a slice. Why would using that instead make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a wrapper for `slice()`. Something like:

```
def nonwrapping_slice(start=0, stop=None, stride=1):
    if stop is not None and stop < 0 and stride > 0:
        stop = None
    return slice(start, stop, stride)
```

Then you can call `nonwrapping_slice(1, -1)` and it will return `slice(1, None, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

`slice` object exposes all its parameters as `start`, `stop` and `step` attributes (readonly). So you can just create a new slice, if necessary:

```py
def slicer(objects, slice_dimensions):
    if slice_dimensions.end == -1:
        # Create a copy slice with end replaced with None
        slice_dimensions = slice(slice_dimensions.start, None, slice_dimensions.step)
    return objects[slice_dimensions]
```

Also, slices have a useful `indices` method, that takes sequence length as argument and outputs a tuple of actual `(start, stop, step)` (without `None` and negative values). You can read more [in docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) (one screen above this anchor - they do not have own heading with href to an anchor)