# Why does foo['bar': 'baz'] raise TypeError rather than SyntaxError?

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror, slice

A question purely for curiosity's sake. This is obviously invalid syntax:

```
foo = {}
foo['bar': 'baz']
```

It's obvious what happened, the developer moved a line out of the dictionary definition but didn't change it from the literal dictionary declaration to the assignment syntax (and has been suitably mocked as a result).

But my question is, why does Python raise `TypeError: unhashable type` here rather than `SyntaxError`? What type is it attempting to hash? Just doing this:

```
'bar': 'baz'
```

is a `SyntaxError`, as is this:

```
['bar': 'baz']
```

so I can't see what type is being created that is unhashable.

Comment: This syntax is used by Pandas, [e.g.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-label) `df1.loc['d':, 'A':'C']`, which selects data labelled from "d" onwards in the rows and from "A" to "C" in the columns.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Using the colon in an indexing operation [generates a `slice` object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936863/python-implementing-slicing-in-getitem/2936876#2936876), which is not hashable.

Comment: Python syntax is often mmoorree flexible than we'd think.

Answer (score 22):

I just want to add some detail to [Ignacio answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157278/why-does-python-raise-typeerror-rather-than-syntaxerror/4157321#4157321) (which is great) and that take me some time to understand and for people like me that didn't get it (i may be the only one that didn't get it because i didn't  see anyone asking i didn't understand but how knows :) ) :

**the first time i wonder what slice ? dictionary indexing don't accept slicing ?**

but this is a stupid question from my part because i forget that python is dynamic (how stupid i'm ) so when python compile the code the fist time python don't know if `foo` is a dictionary or a list so it just read any expression like this foo['foo':'bar'] as a slice , to know that you can just do:

```
def f():
    foo = {}
    foo['bar':'foo']
```

and by using [dis](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html) module you will see that the expression `'bar':'foo'` has been automatically convert to a slice:

```
dis.dis(f)
  2           0 BUILD_MAP                0
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (foo)

  3           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 ('bar')
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 ('foo')
             15 SLICE+3             <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE!!!!!!            
             16 POP_TOP             
             17 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

in the first time i admit i didn't think about this and i did go directly to the source code of python trying to understand why, because the `__getitems__` of list is not like `__getitem__` of a dictionary but now i understand why because if it a slice and slice are unhashable it should raise `unhashable type`, so here is the code of dictionary `__getitem__`:

```
static PyObject *
dict_subscript(PyDictObject *mp, register PyObject *key)
{
    PyObject *v;
    long hash;
    PyDictEntry *ep;
    assert(mp->ma_table != NULL);   
    if (!PyString_CheckExact(key) ||                // if check it's not a string 
        (hash = ((PyStringObject *) key)->ob_shash) == -1) {
        hash = PyObject_Hash(key);    // check if key (sliceobject) is hashable which is false 
        if (hash == -1)
            return NULL;
    } 
    ....
```

Hope this can help some people like me to understand the great response of Ignacio, and sorry if i just duplicate the answer of Ignacio :)

Comment: I think what is so surprising to a human is this: We immediately see that `'bar'` has type `str` and so do not think of slices here. But Python, at this point, apparently only sees that it is a literal. If it were an `int` literal, the slice might be alright -- but the literal's type is apparently not yet considered at this point. (By CPython; has anyone tried this with PyPy?)

Comment: @LutzPrechelt it's more obvious and less surprising to those who have studied compiler theory.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `foo[a:b]` is syntactic sugar for `foo[slice(a, b)]`. That is, you're indexing the dictionary with a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/functions.html#slice) object. This is true regardless of what `foo` is.

In Python 3.11 and below, this raised a `TypeError` because slice objects were not [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3.12/glossary.html#term-hashable). However, [as of Python 3.12](https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html#other-language-changes) (released 2023-10-02), slice objects are now hashable<sup>1</sup>, making their use as dictionary keys valid.

The code in the original question will now raise a `KeyError` instead of a `TypeError`:

```
>>> foo = {}
>>> foo['bar': 'baz']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: slice('bar', 'baz', None)
```

It's now also possible to write

```
foo = {}
foo["bar" : "baz"] = 1
```

which produces the dictionary `{slice('bar', 'baz', None): 1}`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Provided that `start`, `stop`, and `step` are all hashable.