# How to assign values to keys

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I get "unhashable" error when I do the following:

```
a = {}
a["wer":"table.%%maker%%"]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    a["wer":"table.%%maker%%"]
TypeError: unhashable type
```

"wer" key should have "table.%maker%" value here, but I can't insert percentage signs. Wat should I do?

Comment: It took me some time to figure out what _actually_ happens there.

Comment: Related: [Why does Python raise TypeError rather than SyntaxError?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4157278/20862)

Comment: This is nothing at all to do with the percentage sign! a[2:3] gives the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use % characters in dictionary keys, however you assign the value wrong.

```
>>> my_dict = {} 
>>> my_dict['wer'] = 'table.%maker%'
>>> my_dict
{'wer': 'table.%maker%'}
```

You can use the notation with : like this:

```
>>> my_dict = {'wer': 'table.%maker%'}
>>> my_dict
{'wer': 'table.%maker%'}
```

Python has a great documentation which describes how to use data structures [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use this to assign the value to the "wer" key:

```
a["wer"] = "table.%%maker%%"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either set the value during the construction (init) of the dictionary:

```
a = {"wer":"table.%%maker%%"}
```

Or after the dict has been constructed, using the subscript operator:

```
a = {}
a["wer"] = "table.%%maker%%"
```