# Why are slice objects not hashable in python

Tags: python

Why are slice objects in python not hashable:

```
>>> s = slice(0, 10)
>>> hash(s)
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-bdf9773a0874> in <module>()
----> 1 hash(s)

TypeError: unhashable type
```

They seem to be immutable:

```
>>> s.start = 5
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-6710992d7b6d> in <module>()
----> 1 s.start = 5

TypeError: readonly attribute
```

Context, I'd like to make a dictionary that maps python ints or slice objects to some values, something like this:

```
class Foo:
   def __init__(self):
       self.cache = {}
   def __getitem__(self, idx):
       if idx in self.cache:
           return self.cache[idx]
       else:
           r = random.random()
           self.cache[idx] = r
           return r
```

As a workaround I need to special case slices:

```
class Foo:
   def __init__(self):
       self.cache = {}
   def __getitem__(self, idx):
       if isinstance(idx, slice):
           idx = ("slice", idx.start, idx.stop, idx.step)
       if idx in self.cache:
           return self.cache[idx]
       else:
           r = random.random()
           self.cache[idx] = r
           return r
```

This isn't a big deal, I'd just like to know if there is some reasoning behind it.

Comment: Related: [Why does Python raise TypeError rather than SyntaxError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157278/why-does-python-raise-typeerror-rather-than-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue1733184):

> Patch [# 408326](https://bugs.python.org/issue408326) was designed to make assignment to d[:] an error where
> d  is a dictionary.  See discussion starting at
> http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2001-March/072078.html .

Slices were specifically made unhashable so you'd get an error if you tried to slice-assign to a dict.

Unfortunately, it looks like mailing list archive links are unstable. The link in the quote is dead, and the [alternate link I suggested using](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2001-March/033254.html) died too. The best I can point you to is the archive link for [that entire month of messages](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2001-March/thread.html); you can Ctrl-F for `{` to find the relevant ones (and a few false positives).

---

Several decades later, the devs [changed their minds](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/84783), so as of Python 3.12, slices *are* hashable.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: Crap, it is. I wonder why. I'm pretty sure these archives aren't supposed to be pruned. Maybe the links are just really unstable and the 6-digit part changes without warning - archive.org shows a [completely unrelated message](https://web.archive.org/web/20040130161817/https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2001-March/033254.html) in the archives for that URL.

Comment: Now that slices are hashable in Python 3.12., `d[:]` has become valid and no longer raises a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 10):

As a workaround, you can use the `__reduce__()` method that supports pickling slice objects:

```
>>> s
slice(2, 10, None)
>>> s1=s.__reduce__()
>>> s1
(<class 'slice'>, (2, 10, None))
```

While the *slice* is not hashable, it's representation is:

```
>>> hash(s1)
-5954655800066862195
>>> {s1:'pickled slice'}
{(<class 'slice'>, (2, 10, None)): 'pickled slice'}
```

And you can easily reconstitute the slice from that:

```
>>> slice(*s1[1])
slice(2, 10, None)
```

Answer (score 6):

Starting from [Python 3.12](https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html#what-s-new-in-python-3-12) (released 2-Oct-2023), [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/functions.html#slice) objects are [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3.12/glossary.html#term-hashable) (provided that `start`, `stop`, and `step` are ***hashable***).

```
>>> s = slice(1, 10, 2)
>>> hash(s)
5929446288262424708

>>> s = slice(1, 10, [])
>>> hash(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```