# Unhashable type 'slice'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write code that takes websites and skips the first 20 characters and prints the next 100.

This is the code I have so far:

```
i = 0
while i <len(urls):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(urls[i])
    bsobject = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")    
    print(bsobject.body[20:120])
    i+=1
```

I run it and it gives me the error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' "

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: `bsobject.body` is an object, to get its text do something like `bsobject.body.string[20:120]`

Comment: `bsobject.body` is a BeautifulSoup `Tag` object, not a string. It represents the parsed structure of the document's body, not just a sequence of characters.

Comment: Side comment on your loop.  A more pythonic loop would be `for url in urls:`. Then you don't need `i` at all.

Comment: Unrelated, but I'm actually surprised by that error. There doesn't appear to be any way to modify an existing `slice` object, so why wouldn't it be hashable?

Comment: @AndyS I tried doing that and the shell gave me "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable". Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: @chepner: [Slices are unhashable to make `d[:] = whatever` an error when `d` is a dict.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980786/why-are-slice-objects-not-hashable-in-python/29980846#29980846)

Answer (score 0):

```
for url in urls:
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    bsobject = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")
    print(str(bsobject.body)[20:121])
```

This code works, I'm not sure why but it does.

Comment: The comments above answer why `bsobject.body` is a BeautifulSoup `Tag` object, not a string. By `str()`-ing it, you made a string that you can then slice with `[20:121]`.