# Storing tuple from generator in dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, generator, typeerror

I have a generator function which computes some slice positions in a numpy array as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

def __get_slices(data_shape, start, offset, width, patch_size):
    start_indices = [range(start[d] - offset if (start[d] - offset) >= 0 else 0,
                           start[d] - offset + width
                           if (start[d] - offset + width) <= data_shape[d]
                           else data_shape[d])
                     for d in range(len(data_shape))]

    start_coords = product(*start_indices)

    for start_coord in start_coords:
        yield tuple(slice(coord, coord + patch_size) for coord in start_coord)
```

Now I would like to keep this generated tuple in a dictionary which barfs with a `TypeError` exception because I am guessing that the `slice` object is `mutable`. Is there a way to make it immutable through some python functionality and be able to store it in a dictionary?

On python2.7, I get the following error when trying to assign it to a dictionary:

```
TypeError: unhashable type
```

Comment: Ah, slice objects are indeed unhashable, on purpose: [Why are slice objects not hashable in python](//stackoverflow.com/q/29980786)

Comment: @cxw: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'` would be the error. I can certainly reproduce that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah that is interesting. I will try the `reduce` approach as shown in that thread as we;;/

Comment: @Luca: since you are producing only start and stop values in your code, it'd be simpler just to produce tuples with `(start, stop)` values. The `step` value and the `slice` object that `slice.__reduce__` return too are redundant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, `slice()` objects are unhashable, [on purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980786/why-are-slice-objects-not-hashable-in-python), to make sure that `dict[slice] = something` raises an exception:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d[42:81] = 'foobar'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

You'll have to settle for a different object and create slices from those *later*. Store tuples, for example:

```
yield tuple((coord, coord + patch_size) for coord in start_coord)
```

and turn those into slices later when you need to apply these, with `slice(*tup)`.

Comment: That is a good suggestion. Thanks. I will acdcept as soon as the time limit finishes!