# How to make a list object? instance has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, list, object, magic-methods

I am new in Python and in OOP in general. I have an error `"...instance has no attribute '__getitem__'"`, and I understand that the object I have created is not a list. How can I make to be a list object. Here is the class file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt

import math, sys, matrix, os

class Point:
    'Class for points'
    pointCount = 0

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        'initialise the Point from three coordinates'
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        Point.pointCount += 1

    def __str__(self):
        'print the Point'
        return 'Point (%f, %f, %f)' %(self.x, self.y, self.z)

    def copyPoint(self, distance):
        'create another Point at distance from the self Point'
        return Point(self.x + distance[0], self.y + distance[1], self.z + distance[2])

    def __del__(self):
        'delete the Point'
        Point.pointCount -= 1
        #print Point.pointCount
        return '%s deleted' %self
```

I need to have it as a point with three coordinates inside (x, y, z), and those coordinates must be "callable" like in a list instance with [].

I have read similar topics but did not understand much. Please describe it in simple words and with examples.

Comment: what are you passing in as distance? Something indexable? Are you actually trying to use `Point` as a list ie doing `point[0]` etc?

Comment: You need to implement __getitem__: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936863/python-implementing-slicing-in-getitem

Comment: Thanks to everybody for fruitful (and not much) comments and suggestions. For this moment I understand the answer from ecatmur. But I will study also others.
@DougT.: yes, you are right. I am trying to make "indexable" class. Distance is just another indexable variable. It is just a testing example and the "copyPoint" will be redefined later.

Comment: somebody deleted my "Thank you" at the end of the original post. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you consider making your Point class using the [collections.namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#collections.namedtuple) factory function which will make it a subclass of the the built-in `tuple` class. This will save you some boiler-plate work. `namedtuple` class have attributes that can be accessed both by name, such as `p.x` and indexed, like `p[0]`.

They are also very memory efficient like `tuple`s, which may be important if you're going to have a lot of class instances.

You can further specialize what is returned by subclassing it, or use the `verbose` option to capture the source code and modify that as necessary.

There's an example in the documentation linked to above showing it being used to create a 2D `Point` class, which seems like it could be very helpful in your specific use-case.

Here's an example showing how one could define a custom 3D Point class via subclassing:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Point(namedtuple('Point', 'x y z')):
    __slots__ = ()  # prevent creation of instance dictionaries to save memory
    point_count = 0  # instance counter

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Point, self).__init__(*args)
        Point.point_count += 1

    def distance(self, other):
        return sum((self[i]-other[i])**2 for i in xrange(len(self))) ** 0.5

    def copy_point(self, distance):
        'create another Point at distance from the self Point'
        return Point(*[dimension+distance for dimension in self])

p1 = Point(0, 0, 0)
print 'p1:', p1
p2 = p1.copy_point(20)
print 'p2: Point(%s)' % ', '.join(str(p2[i]) for i in xrange(len(p2)))
print 'distance p1 <-> p2: %.3f' % p1.distance(p2)
```

Output:

```
p1: Point(x=1, y=2, z=3)
p2: Point(21, 22, 23)
distance p1 <-> p2: 34.641
```

Note that by using `namedtuple` you don't have to implement a `__getitem__()` yourself, nor write a `__str__()` method. The only reason an `__init__()` was needed was because of the need to increment the class instance counter which was added -- something that `namedtuple`s don't have or do by default.

Comment: @AlexPi: You're welcome. FWIW, I'd also like to point out (no pun intended) that from the sample output you can see that what your `copy_point()` method does is **not** actually creating another point the specified distance away from itself. In other words `Point(21,22,23)` is not 20 units away from `Point(1,2,3)`.

Comment: Yes, I know. It was just for testing. It is not there anymore ;)

Answer (score 5):

Write a `__getitem__` method:

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    return (self.x, self.y, self.z)[item]
```

This constructs a `tuple` of x, y, and z, and uses Python's own indexing facilities to access it.

Alternatively you could switch your own internal storage to be a tuple, and create properties for x, y and z:

```
def __init__(self, x, y, z):
    self.coords = (x, y, z)

@property
def x(self):  # sim. for y, z
    return self.coords[0]

def __getitem__(self, item):
    return self.coords[item]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to define `__getitem__`, but I would probably design the class as follows, which allows attribute and index access to the co-ordinates.

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self._coords = namedtuple('Coords', 'x y z')._make( (x, y, z) )

    @property
    def coords(self):
        return self._coords

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.coords[item]

    def copy_point(self, distance):
        return Point(*(el + distance for el in self.coords))

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point: {}'.format(self.coords)

p = Point(1, 2, 3)
p.copy_point(20), p.coords[0], p.coords.x
# (Point: Coords(x=21, y=22, z=23), 1, 1)
```