# Curious about how django achieves the ORM query optimization

Tags: python, django

I am no python expert and I am curious about how django optimize the following query

```
Model.objects.filter(field = 'abc')[0]
```

Somehow django will intelligently add '`limit 1`' to SQL query like '`select * from model where field = 'abc' limit 1`'

Comment: stupid me, forgot the usage of __getitem__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Model.objects.filter(...)` doesn't actually return a list, it returns a [queryset object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/). When you do `qset[0]`, it calls the `__getitem__` method on querysets, which adds the `limit 1` and executes it. Here's [the source of that method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L173); there's logic for various cases when the result has already been cached or not and so on.

Comment: OK, plus reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936863/python-implementing-slicing-in-getitem makes more sense now...