# Overloading the [] operator in python class to refer to a numpy.array data member

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice

I have written a data container class which essentially contains a numpy ndarray member along with methods to generate time_series masks/cross-sectional masks, fetch the date index (row#) in ring-buffer mode, handle resizing keeping in mind that the data may be a ring buffer, and implement restrictions on the shape/dimensions, etc.

As a result of my class implementation, now that I've to access the data wrapped by this object by explicitly referring to the *.data member. This is cumbersome and I'd like to implement the [] operator in my class such that when called on a instance of my class, it refers to the same operation on the underlying ndarray object. How can I achieve this?

```
def MyArray(object):
    def __init__(self, shape, fill_value, dtype):
        self.shape = shape
        self.fill_value = fill_value
        self.dtype = dtype
        self.data = numpy.empty(shape, fill_value=fill_value, dtype=dtype)

    def reset(self, fill_value=None):
        self.data.fill(fill_value or self.fill_value)

    def resize(self, shape):
        if self.data.ndim != len(shape): raise Exception("dim error")
        if self.data.shape < shape: raise Exception("sizing down not permitted")
        # do resizing
```

Now, if I'd like to use this container elsewhere, I have to use it as such:

```
arr = MyArray(shape=(10000,20), fill_value=numpy.nan, dtype='float')
arr.data[::10] = numpy.NAN
msk = numpy.random.randn(10000,20)<.5
arr.data[~msk] = -1.
```

The fact that I need to explicitly refer to arr.data every time I use this is too cumbersome and error-prone (I'm forgetting the .data suffix in so many places).

Is there any way I can add a few operators such that slicing and indexing on `arr` actually operates on `arr.data` ***implicitly***?

Comment: you have to implement the [`__getitem__`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936863/python-implementing-slicing-in-getitem) attribute

Comment: will this work for cases where arr is used on LHS as well as on RHS?

Comment: @Mindstorm if you're assigning to it, that's `__setitem__`. Just pass the arguments through to `self.data`.

Comment: `self.data.fill(fill_value or self.fill_value)` - what if someone wants to fill it with zeros?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I overlooked that! :|

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to implement the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` magic functions.

A complete overview for the magic methods can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).

```
import numpy as np

class MyArray():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = np.zeros(10)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'MyArray({})'.format(self.data)


a = MyArray()

print(a[9])
print(a[1:5])
a[:] = np.arange(10)
print(a)
```

Which will give you this result:

```
0.0
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
MyArray([ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.])
```

## Inheritance

If you just want to modify or add behaviour of np.ndarray, you could inherit from it. This is a little more complicated than for normal python classes, but implementing your case should be not that hard:

```
import numpy as np


class MyArray(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, shape, fill_value=0, dtype=float):
        data = np.full(shape, fill_value, dtype)
        obj = np.asarray(data).view(cls)
        obj.fill_value = fill_value
        return obj

    def reset(self, fill_value=None):
        if fill_value is not None:
            self.fill_value = fill_value

        self.fill(self.fill_value)
```

For more info, see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html).

Comment: excellent. One question though: would I have to write down every method to fully delegate [] calls on arr to arr.data?

there's one method for a+= b(iadd), one for a*= b(imul). Isn't there a more concise way than enumerating all these methods in my wrapper class?

Comment: You could inherit from array and implement or override methods you need.

Comment: However, this is a little complicated but dealt with in deep here:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html

Comment: I added a inheritance solution to my answer.

Comment: My implementation of the class as an ndarray subclass ran into issues when I try to resize:


    `>>> a.resize((10,2))
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     ValueError: cannot resize an array references or is referenced
     by another array in this way.  Use the resize function.


    >>> a.view(np.ndarray).resize((10,2))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ValueError: cannot resize this array: it does not own its data`

Comment: check out `def __array_finalize__(self, obj)` so you don't get caught out in more exotic circumstances.