# Creating a slice object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

If I have an array `a`, I understand how to slice it in various ways. Specifically, to slice from an arbitrary first index to the end of the array I would do `a[2:]`.

But how would I create a slice object to achieve the same thing? The two ways to create slice objects that are [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) are `slice(start, stop, step)` and `slice(stop)`.

So if I pass a single argument like I would in `a[2:]` the `slice` object would interpret it as the stopping index rather than the starting index.

**Question:** How do I pass an index to the `slice` object with a starting index and get a slice object that slices all the way to the end? I don't know the total size of the list.

Comment: What are you trying to slice? Are you looking for something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936863/python-implementing-slicing-in-getitem ?

Comment: Use "None" for the blank sections.  So the reversing idiom   [::-1]  could be created with:  reversing_slice=slice(None,None,-1)

Comment: @RufusVS: Why add a comment that replicates the accepted answer two years after it was posted?

Comment: @ShadowRanger I must have commented before reading the answers, because I see I upvoted up the accepted answer as well.  I'm older and (hopefully) wiser now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `None` everywhere the syntax-based `slice` uses a blank value:

```
someseq[slice(2, None)]
```

is equivalent to:

```
someseq[2:]
```

Similarly, `someseq[:10:2]` can use a preconstructed `slice` defined with `slice(None, 10, 2)`, etc.