# Why isn't pandas DataFrame's .at accessor not a method?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, accessor

I have been working with pandas lately and of course used the **.at[]** and **.loc[]** accessors.

I don't ask how to use them.

I want to understand **how they work** and **why they are not implemented as methods**.

This might be a general Python topic that I dont know about. Feel free to refer to other threads. I searched but did not find anything useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They call other methods behind the scenes, but I'd guess the decision of not making `loc` and `at` explicit methods is mainly for syntax sugar. In python, it would not be valid syntax to write the slice `:` as an argument to a method, for example `df.loc(:)` etc

Comment: Thanks. This actually makes sense. Do you know how to implement such "calling behind the scenes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, [`.at[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) and [`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) are implemented as sliceable objects to allow [slice syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1026) like `.loc[3:5]`, which is not possible with methods (`.loc(3:5)`).

The way this is implemented in Python is by making `at`/`loc` return a custom object that implements `__getitem__`, like this:

```
class C(object):
  def __getitem__(self, val):
    print val
```

The logic inside `__getitem__` can check the type of `val` passed and behave differently when passed, for example, a list (`.loc[[False, False, False]]`), a function (`.loc[lambda x: ...]`), or a [slice object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2936876/1026) (`.loc[3:5]`)