# What method slices a string in Python?

Tags: python, slice, magic-methods

In Python, the equivalent of [the synntactic sugar] `'bottle'[1]` is `'bottle'.__getitem__(1)`

What is the equivalent method of `'bottle'[1:3]` then?

Comment: The same, but with a `slice` object as a parameter (`a:b(:c)` is syntactic sugar for creating a slice, but only in this context). Depending on the class, the method can accept an integer, string, slice, tuple, tuple of slices, or anything else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Implementing slicing in \_\_getitem\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936863/python-implementing-slicing-in-getitem)

Comment: `bottle[1:3]` means `bottle[ slice(1,3) ]` means  `bottle.__getitem__( slice(1,3) )`