# naive slicing with Python objects

Tags: python, slice

I have a Python class with `__getitem__` that can receive a single integer and return some value,

```py
class Coeffs:
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        # some computation
        return 2 * k ** 3 / 5


c = Coeffs()
print(c[4])
```

```
25.6
```

I would now like to have this class support slices à la `c[1:4]` by just  calling the integer-version `__getitem__` on all values in the slice.

Is there any simple or canonical way to do this?

Comment: Print k and pass a slice in. Should tell you what you want.

Comment: "I have a Python class with `__getitem__` that can receive a single integer and return some tuple" - I don't see a tuple here.

Comment: What you want is to [implement slicing in `__getitem__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936863/implementing-slicing-in-getitem).

Comment: @Griffin Thanks for the comment. Is there a simple way to implement this? I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Is the link proposed by @paime not enough?

Comment: `slice` has start, stop and step just like `range`. That should be all you need unless you get into using `Ellipsis` and/or tuples