# Indexing a numpy ndarray in a custom class

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing, numpy-slicing

I am relatively new to Python and I have written a class that contains a `numpy.ndarray` (containing ordinary Python `int` objects) for storing some data.

I would like to implement `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` in a way that behaves intuitively for someone familiar with `numpy.ndarray`. Here is a heavily simplified version of my first attempt:

```py
import numpy as np

class my_class:
    
    def __init__(self, data : np.ndarray, info):
        self._data = data
        self._info = info
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        data = self._data[key]
        return my_class(np.atleast_1d(data), self._info)
    
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._data[key] = value._data
```

The main issue I have is that `my_class` contains important information (`_info`) about the internal data. Therefore, unlike a `np.ndarray`, I can't just return an `int` when the index is a scalar:

```py
x = my_object[0]  # Require: isinstance(x, my_class) == True
```

That's why my `__getitem__` returns a `my_class` object. This includes a call to `np.atleast_1d()` to ensure the `_data` is always a `np.ndarray`. I tried `np.array()` instead of `np.atleast_1d()`, but that can apparently create 0-dimensional arrays which cannot be indexed.

**Problem**:

In `__setitem__`, if `self._data[key]` is an `int` object and not a `np.ndarray` (for example, because `key` is an `int`), then I end up with nested `np.ndarray` objects inside the array. For example, this script:

```py
import numpy as np
from my_package import my_class

my_object = my_class(np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], dtype=object), "info")
my_object[1,2] = my_object[0,0]
my_object[0,0:2] = my_object[1,1:3]

print(my_object._data)
```

Produces this output:

```
[[5 array([1]) 3]
 [4 5 array([1])]]
```

**Attempted solution**:

I did a lot of searching and found many suggestions related to using `isinstance(key, slice)` to handle slices as a special case. But things seem to be more complicated for `numpy.ndarray`, which supports `tuple` and `list` indexes to handle multi-dimensional indexing and automatic broadcasting, etc. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44170934/4220282) touches very briefly on adding additional special handling for `tuple`, but not `list`.

The best solution I could think of was to instead treat the scalar `int` data as the special case:

```py
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(self._data[key], int):
            self._data[key] = value._data[0]
        else:
            self._data[key] = value._data
```

**Questions**:

- Is there a better way to do this?

  - Are there any glaring pitfalls in my attempted solution?
  - I considered subclassing `np.ndarray` (instead of just having a `np.ndarray` member variable), but it seemed like this would cause all `np.ndarray` functionality to be inherited by `my_class`. I want `my_class` to be intuitive for someone familiar with `np.ndarray`, but I want to control which features are implemented and how.
- Is using `isinstance()` like this a "code smell"? (I feel like it goes against the idea of duck typing in Python).

**Other notes**:

- I am interested in Python 3.x.
- I am aware that using `int` as the data type nullifies some of the advantages of numpy (e.g. execution speed). I need arbitrary precision.

Comment: I think this not the best approach. When you access an item, you expect the return value to be an `int`, and not an array. Who is the actual bearer of `info`? is it the each individual `int` or only your object? Suppose that `object_1` has some info and `object_2` carries a different info. What do you plan to do when someone does `object_1[0] = object_2[0]`?

Comment: @azelcer In my case, the example you describe would throw an error. I could imagine one could implement some kind of automatic casting rules, but I would prefer not to do this. This casting could be a bit like how a `numpy.ndarray` with `dtype=int` can be assigned like `object_1[0] = 2.7` which is cast to `int(2)`. But in my case I would just prefer mismatching "info" to be an error.

Comment: There are many cases you have to tale into account. You can check how [numpy' s unit is implemented](https://docs.enthought.com/scimath/units/unit_numpy.html) for having an idea.