# Access parent class instance attribute from child class instance?

Tags: python, class, instance, parent

How to access "myvar" from "child" in this code example:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        self.myvar = 1

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)

        # this won't work
        Parent.myvar

child = Child()
```

Comment: if your attribute starts with a 'dunder' (e.g. `self.__myvar`) it won't work as python considers it private

Comment: Based on the way your code is written, I could interpret this question in two ways. Either, 1) You're asking "From a subclass, how do I access names that are defined in its superclass?" Or 2) you're confused about the difference between a class variable and an instance variable

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Parent is a class - blue print not an instance of it,
in OOPS to access attributes of an object it requires instance of the same,
Here self/child is instance while Parent/Child are classes...

see the answer below, may clarify your doubts.

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        self.myvar = 1

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)

        # here you can access myvar like below.
        print self.myvar

child = Child()
print child.myvar
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried the normal "self" instance reference. Oh well. Waiting to accept answer...

Comment: Note: in this case, you don't need to have an init method in the subclass for this solution to work.

Comment: For future readers, the `super()` method is preferred in the child class `__init__` instead of the parent class name. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/222877/8213085)

Answer (score 10):

Parent does not have an attribute called myvar.  Only *instances* of parent have that attribute.  From within a method of Child, you can access that attribute with `self.myvar`.

Answer (score 10):

## Alternative to using inheritance

The current answers are coming from an *inheritance* perspective, but this isn't always what you want -- sometimes you might want the child to be an entirely different type of object to the parent, but that still has access to the parent attributes.

For a business analogue, think of Excel Workbooks which have Worksheet children, which themselves have Range children, and so on.

### Only Child

An alternative approach (and not the only one) is to pass the parent as an argument to the child to create a property that corresponds to the parent:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, parent_value):
        self.parent_value = parent_value
        self.child = Child(self)


class Child(object):
    def __init__(self, _parent):
        self.parent = _parent
        self.child_value = 0


new_parent = Parent(1)
print(new_parent.parent_value)        # prints 1

new_child = new_parent.child
print(new_child.child_value)          # prints 0
print(new_child.parent.parent_value)  # prints 1

new_parent.parent_value = 100
print(new_child.parent.parent_value)  # prints 100
```

Note that this instantiates the `child` at the same that that `new_parent` is instantiated. To access the parent's attributes, just go through the `parent` property.

### Multiple Children

You could extend this so that you can create multiple instances of the `Child` class through the `new_parent` object. The code below is one simple way of doing this which replaces the `child` property with a `children` property and an `add_child` method.

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, parent_value):
        self.parent_value = parent_value
        self.children = []

    def add_child(self, child_value):
        new_child = Child(child_value, _parent=self)
        self.children.append(new_child)
        return new_child  # allows add_child to assign a variable


class Child(object):
    def __init__(self, child_value, _parent):
        self.parent = _parent
        self.child_value = child_value


new_parent = Parent(1)

# add 3 Child instances with child_values 2, 4, 8
[new_parent.add_child(v) for v in [2, 4, 8]]

# add another child that utilises the return statement
extra_child = new_parent.add_child(16)

for child in new_parent.children:
    print(child.child_value)          # prints 2, 4, 8, 16
    print(child.parent.parent_value)  # prints 1

new_parent.parent_value = 32
for child in new_parent.children:
    print(child.parent.parent_value)  # prints 32

# prove that extra_child is new_parent.children[3]
extra_child.child_value = 64
print(new_parent.children[3].child_value)  # prints 64
```

Comment: Whilst your answer is good quality, I don't think your answer answers the question as is. The question asks about inheritance not about composition or container classes. And I honestly don't think the OP needs to employ composition here.

Answer (score 0):

One reason your code won't work, and has nothing todo with Parent/Child relationship, is that `myvar` is an instance variable but you're trying to access it like a class variable.

The following treats the variable as class variable and will work as expected:

```py
class Parent():
    myvar = 1
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # Move the definition of myvar outside of the __init__ method, 
        # and remove the self. prefix
        ...

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print(Parent.myvar) # 1

child =  Child()
```

In your original code;

```py
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        self.myvar = 1 # this is an instance variable

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)

        # this won't work
        Parent.myvar #  this treats `myvar` as a class variable
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to initiate the parent class first via so-called proxy object using command "super".

So the code will be like this:

```
class Parent():
  def __init__(self):
      self.myvar = 1

class Child(Parent):
  def __init__(self):
      super.__init__()


child = Child()
print child.myvar
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with this answer. Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: This answer uses python 2.x, which is deprecated. Also, it doesn't really answer the question, because OP asked to access "myvar" inside the "child" class.

Comment: what an expert :) Kim you are wrong. Answered exactly as it was asked. And the solution works on any version of Python. Many people strugeling to understand the concept of parent class. And looks like you one of them.